# Difference between map, applymap and apply methods in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

Can you tell me when to use these vectorization methods with basic examples?

I see that `map` is a `Series` method whereas the rest are `DataFrame` methods. I got confused about `apply` and `applymap` methods though. Why do we have two methods for applying a function to a DataFrame? Again, simple examples which illustrate the usage would be great!

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I believe those functions are not vectorizing methods as they are all involving a loop over the elements they are applied on.

Comment: I can't see a difference here: https://gist.github.com/MartinThoma/e320cbb937afb4ff766f75988f1c65e6

Comment: Marillion, I provided very reductive and simple examples in my answer below. Hope it helps!

Comment: Should I add `DataFrame.pipe()` method to the comparison?

Answer (score 355, accepted):

### Comparing [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) and [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html): Context Matters

The major differences are:

#### Definition

- `map` is defined on Series **only**
- `applymap` is defined on DataFrames **only**
- `apply` is defined on **both**

#### Input argument

- `map` accepts `dict`, `Series`, or callable
- `applymap` and `apply` accept callable only

#### Behavior

- `map` is elementwise for Series
- `applymap` is elementwise for DataFrames
- `apply` also works elementwise but is suited to more complex operations and aggregation. The behaviour and return value depends on the function.

#### Use case (the most important difference)

- `map` is meant for mapping values from one domain to another, so is optimised for performance, e.g.,

  ```
  df['A'].map({1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'})
  ```
- `applymap` is good for elementwise transformations across multiple rows/columns, e.g.,

  ```
  df[['A', 'B', 'C']].applymap(str.strip)
  ```
- `apply` is for applying any function that cannot be vectorised, e.g.,

  ```
  df['sentences'].apply(nltk.sent_tokenize)
  ```

Also see [When should I (not) want to use pandas apply() in my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-not-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code) for a writeup I made a while back on the most appropriate scenarios for using `apply`. (Note that there aren't many, but there are a few— apply is generally *slow*.)

---

### Summarising

|  | `map` | `applymap` | `apply` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Defined on Series? | Yes | No | Yes |
| Defined on DataFrame? | No | Yes | Yes |
| Argument | `dict`, `Series`, or callable<sup>1</sup> | callable<sup>2</sup> | callable |
| Elementwise? | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Aggregation? | No | No | Yes |
| Use Case | Transformation/mapping<sup>3</sup> | Transformation | More complex functions |
| Returns | `Series` | `DataFrame` | scalar, `Series`, or `DataFrame`<sup>4</sup> |

**Footnotes**

1. `map` when passed a dictionary/Series will map elements based on the keys in that dictionary/Series. Missing values will be recorded as NaN in the output.
2. `applymap` in more recent versions has been optimised for some operations. You will find `applymap` slightly faster than `apply` in some cases. My suggestion is to test them both and use whatever works better.
3. `map` is optimised for elementwise mappings and transformation. Operations that involve dictionaries or Series will enable pandas to use faster code paths for better performance.
4. `Series.apply` returns a scalar for aggregating operations, `Series` otherwise. Similarly for `DataFrame.apply`. Note that `apply` also has fastpaths when called with certain NumPy functions such as `mean`, `sum`, etc.

Comment: Why are you saying `apply` is elementwise? Are you considering columns and rows as the elements of a dataframe?

Comment: pandas 2.1.0 (2023-08-30) [renamed](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v2.1.0.html#new-dataframe-map-method-and-support-for-extensionarrays) `df.applymap()` to `df.map()`. The former still works for the time being, but logs a `FutureWarning` recommending to use the more sensible name.

Answer (score 728):

`apply` works on a row / column basis of a DataFrame
`applymap` works element-wise on a DataFrame
`map` works element-wise on a Series

---

Straight from Wes McKinney's [Python for Data Analysis](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023784.do) book, pg. 132 (I highly recommended this book):

> Another frequent operation is applying a function on 1D arrays to each column or row. DataFrame’s apply method does exactly this:

```
In [116]: frame = DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 3), columns=list('bde'), index=['Utah', 'Ohio', 'Texas', 'Oregon'])

In [117]: frame
Out[117]: 
               b         d         e
Utah   -0.029638  1.081563  1.280300
Ohio    0.647747  0.831136 -1.549481
Texas   0.513416 -0.884417  0.195343
Oregon -0.485454 -0.477388 -0.309548

In [118]: f = lambda x: x.max() - x.min()

In [119]: frame.apply(f)
Out[119]: 
b    1.133201
d    1.965980
e    2.829781
dtype: float64
```

> Many of the most common array statistics (like sum and mean) are DataFrame methods,
> so using apply is not necessary.

> Element-wise Python functions can be used, too. Suppose you wanted to compute a formatted string from each floating point value in frame. You can do this with applymap:

```
In [120]: format = lambda x: '%.2f' % x

In [121]: frame.applymap(format)
Out[121]: 
            b      d      e
Utah    -0.03   1.08   1.28
Ohio     0.65   0.83  -1.55
Texas    0.51  -0.88   0.20
Oregon  -0.49  -0.48  -0.31
```

> The reason for the name applymap is that Series has a map method for applying an element-wise function:

```
In [122]: frame['e'].map(format)
Out[122]: 
Utah       1.28
Ohio      -1.55
Texas      0.20
Oregon    -0.31
Name: e, dtype: object
```

Comment: strictly speaking, applymap internally is implemented via apply with a little wrap-up over passed function parameter (rougly speaking replacing `func` to `lambda x: [func(y) for y in x]`, and applying column-wise)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Since `map` and `applymap` both work element-wise, I would expect a single method (either `map` or `applymap`) which would work both for a Series and a DataFrame. Probably there are other design considerations, and Wes McKinney decided to come up with two different methods.

Comment: It's on page 129 in my copy for some reason.  There's no label for second edition or anything.

Comment: Is there a way to do `applymap` along with `groupby` function in pandas?

Comment: How to apply a function on grouped columnwise data?

Comment: I would suggest not using `format` as a function name (as in example 2), since `format` is already a built-in function.

Comment: @everestial007 That is the same as just using `applymap` directly, so what is the point of grouping before an element wise transformation?

Comment: @hhh use `.transform` on pp.264.

Comment: Since the concept of an axis does not exist in a `Series` object, what's the difference between `Series.map` and `Series.apply`?

Answer (score 97):

### Quick Summary

- `DataFrame.apply` operates on entire rows or columns at a time.
- `DataFrame.applymap`, `Series.apply`, and `Series.map` operate on one
  element at time.

`Series.apply` and `Series.map` are similar and often interchangeable.  Some of their slight differences are discussed in [osa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27368948/5405967) below.

Answer (score 45):

Adding to the other answers, in a `Series` there are also [map](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) and [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html).

**Apply can make a DataFrame out of a series**; however, map will just put a series in every cell of another series, which is probably not what you want.

```
In [40]: p=pd.Series([1,2,3])
In [41]: p
Out[31]:
0    1
1    2
2    3
dtype: int64

In [42]: p.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([x, x]))
Out[42]: 
   0  1
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  3  3

In [43]: p.map(lambda x: pd.Series([x, x]))
Out[43]: 
0    0    1
1    1
dtype: int64
1    0    2
1    2
dtype: int64
2    0    3
1    3
dtype: int64
dtype: object
```

Also if I had a function with side effects, such as "connect to a web server", I'd probably use `apply` just for the sake of clarity.

```
series.apply(download_file_for_every_element)
```

**`Map` can use not only a function, but also a dictionary or another series.** Let's say you want to manipulate [permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation).

Take

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 1 4 5 3
```

The square of this permutation is

```
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 5 3 4
```

You can compute it using `map`. Not sure if self-application is documented, but it works in `0.15.1`.

```
In [39]: p=pd.Series([1,0,3,4,2])

In [40]: p.map(p)
Out[40]: 
0    0
1    1
2    4
3    2
4    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Also, .apply() lets you pass in kwargs into the function while .map() doesn't.

Answer (score 23):

@jeremiahbuddha mentioned that apply works on row/columns, while applymap works element-wise. But it seems you can still use apply for element-wise computation....

```
frame.apply(np.sqrt)
Out[102]: 
               b         d         e
Utah         NaN  1.435159       NaN
Ohio    1.098164  0.510594  0.729748
Texas        NaN  0.456436  0.697337
Oregon  0.359079       NaN       NaN

frame.applymap(np.sqrt)
Out[103]: 
               b         d         e
Utah         NaN  1.435159       NaN
Ohio    1.098164  0.510594  0.729748
Texas        NaN  0.456436  0.697337
Oregon  0.359079       NaN       NaN
```

Comment: Good catch with this. The reason this works in your example is because np.sqrt is a ufunc, i.e. if you give it an array, it will broadcast the sqrt function onto each element of the array.  So when apply pushes np.sqrt on each columns, np.sqrt works itself on each of the elements of the columns, so you are essentially getting the same result as applymap.

Answer (score 16):

Probably the simplest explanation the difference between `apply` and `applymap`:

`apply` takes the whole column as a parameter and then assign the result to this column

`applymap` takes the separate cell value as a parameter and assign the result back to this cell.

NB If `apply` returns the single value you will have this value instead of the column after assigning and eventually will have just a row instead of matrix.

Comment: An example showing each case would have been more helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Just wanted to point out, as I struggled with this for a bit

```
def f(x):
    if x < 0:
        x = 0
    elif x > 100000:
        x = 100000
    return x

df.applymap(f)
df.describe()
```

**this does not modify the dataframe itself, has to be reassigned**:

```
df = df.applymap(f)
df.describe()
```

Comment: I sometimes have trouble in figuring out whether you have to reassign or not after doing something with the df. It's mostly trial and error for me, but I bet there is a logic to how it works (that I am missing out).

Comment: in general, a pandas dataframe is only modified by either reassigning `df = modified_df` or  if you set `inplace=True` flag.  Also dataframe will change if you pass a dataframe to a function by reference and the function modifies the dataframe

Comment: This is not entirely true, think of `.ix` or `.where` etc. Not sure what the full explanation is for when you need to re-assign and when not.

Answer (score 7):

Based on the answer of [cs95](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56300992/7951943)

- `map` is defined on Series ONLY
- `applymap` is defined on DataFrames ONLY
- `apply` is defined on BOTH

give some examples

```
In [3]: frame = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 3), columns=list('bde'), index=['Utah', 'Ohio', 'Texas', 'Oregon'])

In [4]: frame
Out[4]:
            b         d         e
Utah    0.129885 -0.475957 -0.207679
Ohio   -2.978331 -1.015918  0.784675
Texas  -0.256689 -0.226366  2.262588
Oregon  2.605526  1.139105 -0.927518

In [5]: myformat=lambda x: f'{x:.2f}'

In [6]: frame.d.map(myformat)
Out[6]:
Utah      -0.48
Ohio      -1.02
Texas     -0.23
Oregon     1.14
Name: d, dtype: object

In [7]: frame.d.apply(myformat)
Out[7]:
Utah      -0.48
Ohio      -1.02
Texas     -0.23
Oregon     1.14
Name: d, dtype: object

In [8]: frame.applymap(myformat)
Out[8]:
            b      d      e
Utah     0.13  -0.48  -0.21
Ohio    -2.98  -1.02   0.78
Texas   -0.26  -0.23   2.26
Oregon   2.61   1.14  -0.93

In [9]: frame.apply(lambda x: x.apply(myformat))
Out[9]:
            b      d      e
Utah     0.13  -0.48  -0.21
Ohio    -2.98  -1.02   0.78
Texas   -0.26  -0.23   2.26
Oregon   2.61   1.14  -0.93


In [10]: myfunc=lambda x: x**2

In [11]: frame.applymap(myfunc)
Out[11]:
            b         d         e
Utah    0.016870  0.226535  0.043131
Ohio    8.870453  1.032089  0.615714
Texas   0.065889  0.051242  5.119305
Oregon  6.788766  1.297560  0.860289

In [12]: frame.apply(myfunc)
Out[12]:
            b         d         e
Utah    0.016870  0.226535  0.043131
Ohio    8.870453  1.032089  0.615714
Texas   0.065889  0.051242  5.119305
Oregon  6.788766  1.297560  0.860289
```

Answer (score 5):

Just for additional context and intuition, here's an explicit and concrete example of the differences.

Assume you have the following function seen below. (
This label function, will arbitrarily split the values into 'High' and 'Low', based upon the threshold you provide as the parameter (x). )

```
def label(element, x):
    if element > x:
        return 'High'
    else:
        return 'Low'
```

In this example, lets assume our dataframe has one column with random numbers.

[image: Df with one column that has random numbers]

If you tried mapping the label function with map:

```
df['ColumnName'].map(label, x = 0.8)
```

You will result with the following error:

```
TypeError: map() got an unexpected keyword argument 'x'
```

Now take the same function and use apply, and you'll see that it works:

```
df['ColumnName'].apply(label, x=0.8)
```

**Series.apply()** can take additional arguments element-wise, while the **Series.map()** method will return an error.

Now, if you're trying to apply the same function to several columns in your dataframe simultaneously, **DataFrame.applymap()** is used.

```
df[['ColumnName','ColumnName2','ColumnName3','ColumnName4']].applymap(label)
```

Lastly, you can also use the apply() method on a dataframe, but the DataFrame.apply() method has different capabilities. Instead of applying functions element-wise, the df.apply() method applies functions along an axis, either column-wise or row-wise. When we create a function to use with df.apply(), we set it up to accept a series, most commonly a column.

Here is an example:

```
df.apply(pd.value_counts)
```

When we applied the pd.value_counts function to the dataframe, it calculated the value counts for all the columns.

Notice, and this is very important, when we used the df.apply() method to transform multiple columns. This is only possible because the pd.value_counts function operates on a series. If we tried to use the df.apply() method to apply a function that works element-wise to multiple columns, we'd get an error:

For example:

```
def label(element):
    if element > 1:
        return 'High'
    else:
        return 'Low'

df[['ColumnName','ColumnName2','ColumnName3','ColumnName4']].apply(label)
```

This will result with the following error:

```
ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', u'occurred at index Economy')
```

In general, we should only use the apply() method when a vectorized function does not exist. Recall that pandas uses vectorization, the process of applying operations to whole series at once, to optimize performance. When we use the apply() method, we're actually looping through rows, so a vectorized method can perform an equivalent task faster than the apply() method.

[image: apply, applymap, map summarization]

Here are some examples of vectorized functions that already exist that you do NOT want to recreate using any type of apply/map methods:

1. Series.str.split()   Splits each element in the Series
2. Series.str.strip()   Strips whitespace from each string in the Series.
3. Series.str.lower()   Converts strings in the Series to lowercase.
4. Series.str.upper()   Converts strings in the Series to uppercase.
5. Series.str.get() Retrieves the ith element of each element in the Series.
6. Series.str.replace() Replaces a regex or string in the Series with another string
7. Series.str.cat() Concatenates strings in a Series.
8. Series.str.extract() Extracts substrings from the Series matching a regex pattern.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding:

From the function point of view:

**If the function has variables that need to compare within a column/ row, use 
`apply`.**

e.g.: `lambda x: x.max()-x.mean()`.

**If the function is to be applied to each element:**

1> If a column/row is located, use `apply`

2> If apply to entire dataframe, use `applymap`

```
majority = lambda x : x > 17
df2['legal_drinker'] = df2['age'].apply(majority)

def times10(x):
  if type(x) is int:
    x *= 10 
  return x
df2.applymap(times10)
```

Comment: Please provide df2 also for better clarity so that we can test your code.

Answer (score 2):

FOMO:

The following example shows [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) applied to a `DataFrame`.

[`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) function is something you do apply on Series only. You cannot apply [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)  on DataFrame.

The thing to remember is that  [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) can do **anything** [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) can, but [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) has **eXtra** options.

The X factor options are: `axis` and `result_type` where `result_type` only works when `axis=1` (for columns).

```
df = DataFrame(1, columns=list('abc'),
                  index=list('1234'))
print(df)

f = lambda x: np.log(x)
print(df.applymap(f)) # apply to the whole dataframe
print(np.log(df)) # applied to the whole dataframe
print(df.applymap(np.sum)) # reducing can be applied for rows only

# apply can take different options (vs. applymap cannot)
print(df.apply(f)) # same as applymap
print(df.apply(sum, axis=1))  # reducing example
print(df.apply(np.log, axis=1)) # cannot reduce
print(df.apply(lambda x: [1, 2, 3], axis=1, result_type='expand')) # expand result
```

As a sidenote, Series [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) function, should not be confused with the Python [`map`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/map.html) function.

The first one is applied on Series, to map the values, and the second one to every item of an iterable.

---

Lastly don't confuse the dataframe [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method with groupby [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) method.

Answer (score 0):

Observation: pandas `applymap` was deprecated with new version, renamed to `map`
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.map.html#pandas.DataFrame.map
[image: pandas updates]