# Apply Function on DataFrame Index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe

What is the best way to apply a function over the index of a Pandas `DataFrame`?
Currently I am using this verbose approach:

```
pd.DataFrame({"Month": df.reset_index().Date.apply(foo)})
```

where `Date` is the name of the index and `foo` is the name of the function that I am applying.

Comment: does `df.index.map(foo)` work?

Comment: It "works", but it returns a numpy array rather than a Pandas Series.

Comment: what's your final goal? you can pass array to DataFrame constructor. Or do something like `pd.Series(df.index).apply(foo)`

Comment: It totally depends what the function is...

Comment: Following from @HYRY if you just want to modify the index of an existing DataFrame you can do `df.index = df.index.map(foo)`

Answer (score 143):

As already suggested by HYRY in the comments, [Series.map](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) is the way to go here. Just set the index to the resulting series.

Simple example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'d': [1, 2, 3]}, index=['FOO', 'BAR', 'BAZ'])
df
        d
FOO     1
BAR     2
BAZ     3

df.index = df.index.map(str.lower)
df
        d
foo     1
bar     2
baz     3
```

## Index != Series

As pointed out by @OP. the `df.index.map(str.lower)` call returns a numpy array.
This is because dataframe indices *are* based on numpy arrays, not Series.

The only way of making the index into a Series is to create a Series from it.

```
pd.Series(df.index.map(str.lower))
```

#### Caveat

The `Index` class now subclasses the `StringAccessorMixin`, which means that you can do the above operation as follows

```
df.index.str.lower()
```

This still produces an Index object, not a Series.

Comment: With a multi-index, you can use slicing if you want to use both items in your function, e.g. `x[0]` and `x[1]`.

Comment: A bit shorter way `df.index.map(str.lower)`

Comment: @JohnGalt Thanks for pointing it out. It's not only shorter, but faster, since str.lower is a compiled cython function and the lambda function I wrote is not.

Comment: how does that modify if the function I want to apply needs some argument? e.g. I have a float index and I want to round each value to 2 decimal places

Answer (score 27):

You can convert an index using its `to_series()` method, and then either `apply` or `map`, according to your needs.

```py
ret = df.index.map(foo)                # Returns pd.Index
ret = df.index.to_series().map(foo)    # Returns pd.Series
ret = df.index.to_series().apply(foo)  # Returns pd.Series
```

All of the above can be assigned directly to a new or existing column of `df`:

```py
df["column"] = ret
```

Just for completeness: [`pd.Index.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html), [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`pd.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) all operate element-wise. I often use `map` to apply lookups represented by `dicts` or `pd.Series`. `apply` is more generic because you can pass any function along with additional `args` or `kwargs`. The differences between `apply` and `map` are further discussed in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798153). I don't know why `pd.Index.apply` was omitted.

Comment: thank you for your detailed response, the third option got me out of a hole.

Comment: I found the 3rd example useful, as the index is preserved in the Series that is returned.

Answer (score 13):

Assuming that you want to make a column in you're current DataFrame by applying your function "foo" to the index. You could write...

```
df['Month'] = df.index.map(foo)
```

To generate the series alone you could instead do ...

```
pd.Series({x: foo(x) for x in foo.index})
```

Comment: Using for loops in the pandas/numpy echo-system is highly discouraged. It is very memory inefficient and easily crashes with larger datasets.

Answer (score 6):

A lot of answers are returning the Index as an array, which loses information about the index name etc (though you could do `pd.Series(index.map(myfunc), name=index.name)`). It also won't work for a MultiIndex.

The way that I worked with this is to use "rename":

```
mix = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([[1, 'hi'], [2, 'there'], [3, 'dude']], names=['num', 'name'])
data = np.random.randn(3)
df = pd.Series(data, index=mix)
print(df)
num  name 
1    hi       1.249914
2    there   -0.414358
3    dude     0.987852
dtype: float64

# Define a few dictionaries to denote the mapping
rename_dict = {i: i*100 for i in df.index.get_level_values('num')}
rename_dict.update({i: i+'_yeah!' for i in df.index.get_level_values('name')})
df = df.rename(index=rename_dict)
print(df)
num  name       
100  hi_yeah!       1.249914
200  there_yeah!   -0.414358
300  dude_yeah!     0.987852
dtype: float64
```

The only trick with this is that your index needs to have unique labels b/w different multiindex levels, but maybe someone more clever than me knows how to get around that. For my purposes this works 95% of the time.

Comment: `rename` has a `level` argument (nowadays?). So this removes the ambiguity: `df.rename(index=rename_dict0, level=0).rename(index=rename_dict1, level=1)`.