# Pandas - apply transformation on index of DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my code

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'A':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'B':[10, 20, 30, 44, 48, 81]})
a = x['A'].apply(lambda t: t%2==0) # works
c = x.index.apply(lambda t: t%2==0) # error
```

How can I make that code work in the easiest way? I know how to `reset_index()` and then treat it as a column, but I was curious if it's possible to operate on the index as if it's a regular column.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20025325/apply-function-on-dataframe-index

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to convert the `Index` to a `Series` using [`to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html):

```
c = x.index.to_series().apply(lambda t: t%2==0)
```

if you want to call `apply` as `Index` objects have no `apply` method

There are a limited number of methods and operations for an Index: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#modifying-and-computations

Answer (score 2):

Pandas index have a [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Index.map.html) method:

```
c = x.index.map(lambda t: t%2==0)   # Index([True, False, True, False, True, False], dtype='object')
```

Note that this returns a Index, not a pandas Series.

Answer (score 2):

Pandas hasn't implemented `pd.Index.apply`. You can, for simple calculations, use the underlying NumPy array:

```
c = x.index.values % 2 == 0
```

As opposed to `lambda`-based solutions, this takes advantage of vectorised operations.