# pandas - create a new calculated field

Tags: python, pandas

How do I create a new field in pandas that is a log of another field?

```
df =pd.read_csv('tseries.txt',parse_dates=True,index_col=0)
df['exr_ln']=math.log(df['exr'])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/chaos/forecast.py", line 212, in <module>
    df['exr_ln']=math.log(df['exr'])
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas has a lot of built-in functionality to apply functions in a vectorized way over Series and DataFrames. When that fails, you can use `map` or `apply`. Here `map` will applies a function element-wise on a Series.

`df['exr_ln'] = df['exr'].map(math.log)`

For more on map and apply, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798153/difference-between-map-applymap-and-apply-methods-in-pandas).