# pyspark's flatMap in pandas

Tags: pandas, pyspark

Is there an operation in pandas that does the same as [flatMap](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.flatMap) in pyspark?

flatMap example:

```
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize([2, 3, 4])
>>> sorted(rdd.flatMap(lambda x: range(1, x)).collect())
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
```

So far I can think of `apply` followed by `itertools.chain`, but I am wondering if there is a one-step solution.

Comment: If this is a pure pandas question then it would help to more fully explain what you are trying to do (for folks not familiar with flatMap, which may be a lot of people here!).  Sample data, desired results, etc.

Answer (score 8):

There's a hack. I often do something like

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]})

In [3]: df['x'].apply(pd.Series).unstack().reset_index(drop=True)
Out[3]:
0     1
1     3
2     2
3     4
4   NaN
5     5
dtype: float64
```

The introduction of `NaN` is because the intermediate object creates a `MultiIndex`, but for a lot of things you can just drop that:

```
In [4]: df['x'].apply(pd.Series).unstack().reset_index(drop=True).dropna()
Out[4]:
0    1
1    3
2    2
3    4
5    5
dtype: float64
```

This trick uses all pandas code, so I would expect it to be reasonably efficient, though it might not like things like very different sized lists.

Comment: If you replace reset_index(drop=True) with reset_index(level=0, drop=True), this also maintains the old index

Answer (score 3):

Since July 2019, Pandas offer `pd.Series.explode` to unnest frames. Here's a possible implementation of `pd.Series.flatmap` based on explode and map. Why?

- `flatmap` operations should be a subset of `map`, not `apply`. check this thread for `map`/`applymap`/`apply` details [Difference between map, applymap and apply methods in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798153/difference-between-map-applymap-and-apply-methods-in-pandas)

```py
import pandas as pd
from typing import Callable

def flatmap(
    self,
    func:Callable[[pd.Series],pd.Series],
    ignore_index:bool=False):
    return self.map(func).explode(ignore_index)
pd.Series.flatmap = flatmap

# example
df = pd.DataFrame([(x,y) for x,y in zip(range(1,6),range(6,16))], columns=['A','B'])
print(df.head(5))
#    A   B
# 0  1   6
# 1  2   7
# 2  3   8
# 3  4   9
# 4  5  10
print(df.A.flatmap(range,False))
# 0    NaN
# 1      0
# 2      0
# 2      1
# 3      0
# 3      1
# 3      2
# 4      0
# 4      1
# 4      2
# 4      3
# Name: A, dtype: object
print(df.A.flatmap(range,True))
# 0     0
# 1     0
# 2     1
# 3     0
# 4     1
# 5     2
# 6     0
# 7     1
# 8     2
# 9     3
# 10    0
# 11    1
# 12    2
# 13    3
# 14    4
# Name: A, dtype: object
```

As you can see, the main issue is **the indexing**. You could ignore it and just reset, but then you're better of using NumPy or std lists, as indexing is one of the key pandas' points. If you do not care about indexing at all, you could reuse the idea of the solution above, change `pd.Series.map` to `pd.DataFrame.applymap` and `pd.Series.explode` to `pd.DataFrame.explode` and forcing `ignore_index=True`.

Answer (score 1):

there are three steps to solve this question.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]})
df_new = df['x'].apply(pd.Series).unstack().reset_index().dropna()
df_new[['level_1',0]]`
```

[image: result picture]

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that the answer is "no, not efficiently."

Pandas isn't built for nested data like this.  I suspect that the case you're considering in Pandas looks a bit like the following:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]})

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
           x
0     [1, 2]
1  [3, 4, 5]
```

And that you want something like the following

```
    x
0   1
0   2
1   3
1   4
1   5
```

It is far more typical to [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your data in Python before you send it to Pandas.  If Pandas did do this then it would probably only be able to operate at slow Python speeds rather than fast C speeds.

Generally one does a bit of munging of data before one uses tabular computation.

Comment: Can you refer to a reading reference supporting the "Pandas isn't built for nested data like this." statement? Me and other Pandas beginners would like to know more! :)

Comment: Have you read through the Pandas documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/ ?  It's pretty comprehensive.

Comment: Related but contain more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-do-i-unnest-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: `flatMap` is used where a function returns a collection of values that you want to concatenate. This has nothing to do with normalisation.