# Dataframe: extract multiple parents from single ID and count occurrences

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bigdata

Don't know if the headline is good enough. Feel free to adjust it!

Here's the **situation**: I got a dataframe that is basically a product catalogue. In this there are two important columns. One is the product ID and one is a 12-digit category. This is some sample data. Of course, the original data contains many more products, more columns and many different categories.

```
products = [
    {'category': 110401010601, 'product': 1000023},
    {'category': 110401020601, 'product': 1000024},
    {'category': 110401030601, 'product': 1000025},
    {'category': 110401040601, 'product': 1000026},
    {'category': 110401050601, 'product': 1000027}]

pd.DataFrame.from_records(products)
```

**The task** is to use the 12-digit category number to form parent-categories and use those parents to count the number of products that match that parent category. The parent-categories are formed in 2-digit steps. The counts per parent are later on used to find a parent for each product that has a minimum number of records (let's say 12 children). Of course, the shorter the number gets, the more products will match that number. Here's an example parent structure:

```
110401050601 # product category
1104010506 # 1st parent
11040105 # 2nd parent
110401 # 3rd parent
1104 # 4th parent
11 # 5th super-parent
```

You see that there may be many more products matching for instance the 1104 instead of just the 110401050601.

**Idea 1 for Small Data:** As long as you have small or medium size data fully loaded into a Pandas dataframe, this is an easy task. I solved it with this code. **The disadvantage** is that this code assumes that all data is in memory and each loop is another select into the full dataframe, which is not good in terms of performance. Example: for 100.000 rows and 6-parent groups (formed from the 12-digits) you may end up with 600.000 select via `DataFrame.loc[...]` thus growing gradually (worst case). To prevent this I'm breaking the loop if the parent has been seen before. Remark: the `df.shape[0]` method is similar to `len(df)`.

```
df = df.drop_duplicates()
categories = df['category'].unique()

counts = dict()
for cat in categories:
    counts[cat] = df.loc[df['category'] == cat].shape[0]

    for i in range(10,1,-2):
        parent = cat[:i]

        if parent not in counts:
            counts[parent] = df.loc[df['category'].str.startswith(parent)].shape[0]
        else:
            break

counts = {key: value for key, value in counts.items() if value >= MIN_COUNT}
```

Which results in something like this (using parts of my original data):

```
{'11': 100,
 '1103': 7,
 '110302': 7,
 '11030202': 7,
 '1103020203': 7,
 '110302020301': 7,
 '1104': 44,
 '110401': 15,
 '11040101': 15,
 '1104010106': 15,
 '110401010601': 15}
```

**Idea 2 for Big Data using flatmap-reduce:** Now imagine you have much much more data which is loaded row-wise and you want to achieve the same thing as above. I was thinking of using `flatmap` to split the category number into its parents (one to many) using a 1-counter for each parent and then apply `groupby-key` to get the count for all possible parents. **The advantage** of this version is, that it doesn't need all data at once and that it is not doing any selects into the dataframe. But in the flatmap-step the number of rows increases by a factor of 6 (due to 12-digit category number split into 6 groups). Since Pandas has no `flatten/flatmap` method, I had to apply a work-around using `unstack` (for explanation [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31080258/pysparks-flatmap-in-pandas)).

```
df = df.drop_duplicates()
counts_stacked = df['category'].apply(lambda cat: [(cat[:i], 1) for i in range(10,1,-2)])
counts = counts_stacked.apply(pd.Series).unstack().reset_index(drop=True)

df_counts = pd.DataFrame.from_records(list(counts), columns=['category', 'count'])
counts = df_counts.groupby('category').count().to_dict()['count']
counts = {key: value for key, value in counts.items() if value >= MIN_COUNT}
```

**Question:** Both solutions are fine, but I wonder if there is a more elegant way to achieve the same result. I feel that I've missed something.

Comment: What are you trying to optimize? Speed, memory use, readability? Elegance is a bit vague.

Comment: Basically I’m looking for a version that can be easily transferred to PySpark or Apache Beam that are all somewhat line based on the map-reduce concept. My second code is similar to that but is exploding the number of lines a lot. Here I’m interested if there is another way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can using `cumsum` here

```
df.category.astype(str).str.split('(..)').apply(pd.Series).replace('',np.nan).dropna(1).cumsum(1).stack().value_counts()
Out[287]: 
11              5
1104            5
110401          5
11040102        1
110401050601    1
1104010206      1
110401040601    1
11040101        1
1104010106      1
110401010601    1
110401020601    1
11040104        1
110401030601    1
11040103        1
1104010406      1
1104010306      1
11040105        1
1104010506      1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Nice. Didn’t know that you can use split(‘(..)’). This solution strongly depends on pandas and won’t work in PySpark or Apache Beam I guess

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution using Apache Beam SDK for Python. This is compatible to Big Data using the map-reduce paradigm. The sample file should contain the product id as first column and 12-digit category as second column using the `;` as separator. The elegance of this code is that you can nicely see each transformation per line.

```
# Python 2.7

import apache_beam as beam
FILE_IN = 'my_sample.csv'
SEPARATOR = ';'

# the collector target must be created outside the Do-Function to be globally available
results = dict()

# a custom Do-Function that collects the results
class Collector(beam.DoFn):    
    def process(self, element):
        category, count = element
        results[category] = count
        return { category: count }


# This runs the pipeline locally.
with beam.Pipeline() as p:
    counts = (p
     | 'read file row-wise' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(FILE_IN, skip_header_lines=True)
     | 'split row' >> beam.Map(lambda line: line.split(SEPARATOR))
     | 'remove useless columns' >> beam.Map(lambda words: words[0:2])
     | 'remove quotes' >> beam.Map(lambda words: [word.strip('\"') for word in words])
     | 'convert from unicode' >> beam.Map(lambda words: [str(word) for word in words])
     | 'convert to tuple' >> beam.Map(lambda words: tuple(words))
     | 'remove duplicates' >> beam.RemoveDuplicates()
     | 'extract category' >> beam.Map(lambda (product, category): category)
     | 'create parent categories' >> beam.FlatMap(lambda cat: [cat[:i] for i in range(12,1,-2)])
     | 'group and count by category' >> beam.combiners.Count.PerElement()
     | 'filter by minimum count' >> beam.Filter(lambda count: count[1] >= MIN_COUNT)
     | 'collect results' >> beam.ParDo(collector)
    )

result = p.run()
result.wait_until_finish()

# investigate the result; 
# expected is a list of tuples each consisting of the category and its count
print(results)
```

The code is written in Python 2.7 since the Apache Beam SDK for Python does not support Python 3, yet.