# Applying complex function to several timeseries

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

What I am trying to achieve is this:
I have several Timeseries, which I need to combine on a per-point-basis and return the result as a single new timeseries.

I understand that you can use various `numpy` functions on Series in `pandas`, but I am unclear on how to apply complex functions to several timeseries.

The Function I want to apply:

```
def direction_day(y_values):
    # taking a numpy array of floats
    sig_sum = np.sum(np.sign(y_values))
    abs_sum = np.sum(np.abs(np.sign(y_values)))

    return (sig_sum / abs_sum)
```

Example of my current `TimeSeries` Objects:

```
def ret_random_ts():
    dates = ['2016-1-{}'.format(i)for i in range(1,21)]
    values = [np.random.randn(4,3) for i in range(20)]

    return pd.Series(values, index=dates)
```

Of course I can always just loop through the `TimeSeries` with `for` loops and glue them together.
I was wondering, however, if there was an option to pass a function to a `TimeSeries` object containing multiple values per date, and apply that function for each date?

I.e.:

```
ts = ret_random_ts()
ts.apply_func(direction_day,Series['Dates'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map`:

```
ts.map(direction_day)

2016-1-1     0.166667
2016-1-2     0.000000
2016-1-3     0.166667
2016-1-4     0.666667
2016-1-5     0.000000
2016-1-6    -0.166667
```

Or `apply` (produce the same result)

```
ts.apply(direction_day)
```

Or `apply` with lambda (produce the same result)

```
ts.apply(lambda y: direction_day(y))
```

Each method will be applied **element-wise** (for value of a `Series`) since a `Series` has only one column. `DataFrame` have methods working element-wise or by **row / column** (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798153/difference-between-map-applymap-and-apply-methods-in-pandas) for more detail). In your case, values of the `Series` are arrays of arrays, so the entire array will be passed to the function. If you want more control, I suggest using a `DataFrame` instead of a `Series` containing an array which is not the preferred way to work in pandas. But your data has more than two dimensions (3), pandas also provide another data structure called [Panel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html?highlight=panel#panels) but I have never worked with `Panel` so I cannot help you.

As an example, this kind of array will be passed to your `direction_day` function:

```
[[ 1.76405235,  0.40015721,  0.97873798],
       [ 2.2408932 ,  1.86755799, -0.97727788],
       [ 0.95008842, -0.15135721, -0.10321885],
       [ 0.4105985 ,  0.14404357,  1.45427351]]
```

Comment: Would this apply the function to just one y value per datapoint, or would it apply it to all y values? 
Since my function takes a list/iterable, would the y values be passed as such to my function? Because this seems to be the case in my test runs.

Comment: I have just completed my answer to give some precisions. I have run both function and it runs (it does not produce an error), but I don't know if the result matches your expectations.

Comment: Hm. I'm not sure it does, but your answer has given me some insight on the matter. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
ts.apply(direction_day)
2016-1-1    -0.333333
2016-1-2    -0.500000
2016-1-3    -0.333333
2016-1-4     0.000000
2016-1-5     0.166667
2016-1-6     0.666667
2016-1-7     0.166667
2016-1-8     0.166667
2016-1-9     0.333333
2016-1-10    0.000000
2016-1-11   -0.333333
2016-1-12    0.166667
2016-1-13   -0.500000
2016-1-14    0.166667
2016-1-15    0.000000
2016-1-16   -0.333333
2016-1-17   -0.166667
2016-1-18   -0.166667
2016-1-19   -0.166667
2016-1-20    0.000000
dtype: float64
```