# Pandas Series Apply Method

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I've been using pandas apply method for both series and dataframe, but I am obviously still missing something, because I'm stumped on a simple function i'm trying to execute.

This is what I was doing:

```
def minmax(row):
    return (row - row.min())/(row.max() - row.min())

row.apply(minmax)
```

but, this returns an all zero Series.  For example, if

```
row = pd.Series([0, 1, 2])
```

then

```
minmax(row)
```

returns [0.0, 0.5, 1.0], as desired. But, row.apply(minmax) returns [0,0,0].

I believe this is because the series is of ints and the integer division returns 0. However, I don't understand,

- why it works with minmax(row) (shouldn't it act the same?), and
- how to cast it correctly in the apply function to return appropriate float values (i've tried to cast it using .astype and this gives me all NaNs... which I also don't understand)
- if apply this to a dataframe, as df.apply(minmax) it also works as desired. (edit added)

i suspect i'm missing something fundamental in how the apply works... or being dense. either way, thanks in advance.

Comment: what version of pandas are you using? I can't replicate this.

Comment: ah... well, that gives me some encouragement. also, i just added that applying it to a dataframe works just fine, as is.  pandas 0.18.0...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `row.apply(minmax)` on a `Series` **only the values** are passed to the function. This is called **element-wise**.

> Invoke function on values of Series. Can be ufunc (a NumPy function that applies to the entire Series) or a Python function that only works on single values.

When you call `row.apply(minmax)` on a `DataFrame` either rows (default) or columns are passed to the function (according to the value of `axis`).

> Objects passed to functions are Series objects having index either the DataFrame’s index (axis=0) or the columns (axis=1). Return type depends on whether passed function aggregates, or the reduce argument if the DataFrame is empty. This is called **row-wise** or **column-wise**.

This is why your example works as expected on the `DataFrame` and not on the `Series`. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35819874/4413446) for information on mapping functions to `Series`.

Comment: Ah! I was ignoring that the only functions that can be applied to the entire series are numpy functions. So, in this particular case, apply is working the same as map would, i believe. Can you explain why python doesn't get upset about applying .min() and .max() to the values? In this context, it doesn't make sense and i would have expected to error.  I did this, row.apply(lambda x: x  - x.min()), to test out what you were saying, and it also returns [0,0,0] so i gather x.min() == x but i would think it would error. thanks!

Comment: This is weird, in my test the call of the function on the `Series` produces an error `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'min'`. This seems to be the expected behavior.

Comment: Hmm. what pandas are you using? I've recreated it w/o error both in Juypter (where i was working) and as a script in PyCharm. Raising an error would have saved me a lot of time. :)  I'll update to 0.18.1 and see. thanks again.