# pandas DataFrame, how to apply function to a specific column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have read the docs of [DataFrame.apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

> DataFrame.apply(func, axis=0, broadcast=False, raw=False, reduce=None, args=(), **kwds)¶
>   Applies function along input axis of DataFrame.

So, How can I apply a function to a specific column?

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: data = {'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6], 'C': [7, 8, 9]}
In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(data)
In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
In [5]: def addOne(v):
...:        v += 1
...:        return v
...: 
In [6]: df.apply(addOne, axis=1)
Out[6]: 
   A  B   C
0  2  5   8
1  3  6   9
2  4  7  10
```

I want to addOne to every value in `df['A']`, not all columns. How can I do that with `DataFrame.apply`.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Avoid using `apply` as much as possible. If you're not sure you need to use it, you probably don't. I recommend taking a look at [When should I ever want to use pandas apply() in my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54432583/4909087).

Comment: @coldspeed That is nice, good question and answers in depth.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The answer is,

```
df['A'] = df['A'].map(addOne)
```

and maybe you would be better to know about [the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798153/difference-between-map-applymap-and-apply-methods-in-pandas) of `map`, `applymap`, `apply`.

but if you insist to use `apply`, you could try like below.

```
def addOne(v):
    v['A'] += 1
    return v

df.apply(addOne, axis=1)
```

Comment: `can we apply same function at a time on both A and B.`

Comment: @dondapati Sure, you can simply add v['B'] += 1 inside addOne function. Pandas apply function gets each row as v when axis=1.

Answer (score 20):

One simple way would be:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: x+1)
```

Comment: I did your suggestion by doing:

 df['A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: datetime.fromtimestamp(float(x)/1000.)) and I got:

"A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead. "
Any suggestions?

Comment: @Catarina Nogueira Try adding .copy() at the very end e.g. apply(...).copy()

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution. You're mutating the DataFrame, while iterating over itself. I would frist make a copy of the DataFrame. See here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/gotchas.html#gotchas-udf-mutation

Comment: @Paul Good Suggestion. Making a copy before do UDF function can aviod some unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else looking for a solution that allows for pipe-ing:

```
identity = lambda x: x

def transform_columns(df, mapper):
    return df.transform(
        {
            **{
                column: identity
                for column in df.columns
            },
            **mapper
        }
    )

# you can monkey-patch it on the pandas DataFrame (but don't have to, see below)
pd.DataFrame.transform_columns = transform_columns

(
    pd.DataFrame(data)
    .rename(columns={'A': 'A1'})   # just to demonstrate the motivation
    .transform_columns({'A1': add_one})
)
```

This also allows to:

```
pd.DataFrame(data).transform_columns({
    'A': add_one,
    'B': add_two,
})
```

And if you do not want to monkey-patch DataFrame, you can always use it with `pipe`:

```
pd.DataFrame(data).pipe(transform_columns, {'A': add_one})
```

It would be great if this was naively supported by pandas though.

The snippets above are CC0.

Answer (score 2):

you can use .apply() with lambda function to solve this kind of problems.

Consider, your dataframe is something like this,

```
A | B | C
----------
1 | 4 | 7
2 | 5 | 8
3 | 6 | 9
```

The function which you want to apply:

```
def addOne(v):
v += 1
return v
```

So if you write your code like this,

```
df['A'] = df.apply(lambda x: addOne(x.A), axis=1)
```

You will get:

```
A | B | C
----------
2 | 4 | 7
3 | 5 | 8
4 | 6 | 9
```