# Use function (not using lambda) with apply method for pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add column according to the existing column in dataframe following this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36213383/pandas-dataframe-how-to-apply-function-to-a-specific-column).
Since there are many if case, I defined the if case as function (getDirection method) and tried to call by apply method(addDirection method).
Howerver, I got following error.

```
TypeError: getDirection() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Can anyone tell how I can call function by apply for dataframe?
Code is shown below.

```
def addDirection(self):
    group=self.group
    group['direction']=group['Azimuth [deg]'].apply(self.getDirection)

   def getDirection(angle):
        if angle < 11.25 or angle >= 348.75:
            return "N"
        elif angle < 33.75 and angle >= 11.25:
            return "NNE"
        elif angle < 56.25 and angle >= 33.75:
            return "NE"
        elif angle < 78.75 and angle >= 56.25:
            return "ENE"
        elif angle < 101.25 and angle >= 78.75:
            return "E"
        elif angle < 123.75 and angle >= 101.25:
            return "ESE"
        elif angle < 146.25 and angle >= 123.75:
            return "SE"
        elif angle < 168.75 and angle >= 146.25:
            return "SSE"
        elif angle < 191.25 and angle >= 168.75:
            return "S"
        elif angle < 213.75 and angle >= 191.25:
            return "SSW"
        elif angle < 236.25 and angle >= 213.75:
            return "SW"
        elif angle < 258.75 and angle >= 236.25:
            return "WSW"
        elif angle < 281.25 and angle >= 258.75:
            return "W"
        elif angle < 303.75 and angle >= 281.25:
            return "WNW"
        elif angle < 326.25 and angle >= 303.75:
            return "NW"
        elif angle < 348.75 and angle >= 326.25:
            return "NNW"
```

Comment: How did you `apply` the `getDirection()` method?

Comment: `getDirection` appears to be a method in some class, not a regular function.

Comment: @akilat90 Referring to this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36213383/pandas-dataframe-how-to-apply-function-to-a-specific-column), I suppose below script is applying the getDirection() method to dataframe.   'group['direction']=group['Azimuth [deg]'].apply(self.getDirection)'

Comment: This is a lot more concisely implemented as a `list` lookup: `return ["N", "NNE", "NE, "ENE", ...][int((angle*100)//1125]`.

Comment: How are you calling addDirection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When calling `self.getDirection(a)`, you are **implicitly calling `getDirection(self, a)`**. This is why the error message states that two arguments were given instead of one (`self` and the element of the series).

The way you call the function (prepending `self.`) implies that it is not a *static method*, but rather an *instance method*. Instance methods are defined inside a class; their result typically depends on the internal state of the object (instance of the class) you are calling it on.

If you *called the function as an instance method by mistake*, **you should write `apply(getDirection)`** instead of `apply(self.getDirection)`. Most likely this is what you want, since the function's outcome depends only on `angle` and not on any object's internal state.

If you *want `getDirection` to be an instance method*, **define the function as `def getDirection(self, a)`**. You don't have to change anything else.

See also [this answer on instance and class methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17134709/1234438).

Answer (score 2):

As @Cornflex said is because you are passing additional paramter using self so you got that error. Either do `def getDirection(self,angle)` or just `apply.(getDirection)`

Since its pandas instead of that many if else's we can just do binning using pd.cut i.e

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Azimuth [deg]':[300,340,150]})
bins = [11.25, 33.75, 56.25, 78.75, 101.25, 123.75, 146.25, 168.75, 191.25, 213.75, 236.25, 258.75, 281.75, 303.75, 326.25, 348.75]

labels = ['NNE', 'NE', 'ENE', 'E', 'ESE', 'SE', 'SSE', 'S', 'SSW', 'SW', 'WSW', 'W', 'WNW', 'NW', 'NNW']

pd.cut(df['Azimuth [deg]'],bins=bins,labels=labels).fillna('N') # fillna is for your first condition.

0    WNW
1    NNW
2    SSE
Name: Azimuth [deg], dtype: category
Categories (15, object): [NNE < NE < ENE < E ... W < WNW < NW < NNW]
In [557]:

df['Azimuth [deg]'].apply(getDirection)

0    WNW
1    NNW
2    SSE
Name: Azimuth [deg], dtype: object
```