# Convert IP address to integer in dask dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I need to train an ML model using a large dataset. For this I'm using the dask library.

My dataset contains IP addresses (column index 0 and 2). I'm trying to convert these IP addresses into integer using the ipaddress python library. A sample of the dataset is given below:

| IP Add Src | Port | IP Add Dest. | Port |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9.166.0.5 | 1305 | 149.17.12.8 | 21 |
| 9.166.0.5 | 1305 | 149.17.12.8 | 21 |
| 9.166.0.5 | 1305 | 149.17.12.8 | 21 |
| 9.166.0.5 | 1305 | 149.17.12.8 | 21 |
| 9.166.0.5 | 1305 | 149.17.12.8 | 21 |
| 9.166.0.5 | 1305 | 149.17.12.8 | 21 |

Initially when using pandas dataframe, I used the following to convert the Ip addresses:

`df['IP Add Src'] = df['IP Add Src'].apply(lambda x: int(ipaddress.IPv4Address(x)))`

From what I've read, with dask, there are the apply, map_partitions and map functions which are available.

However, I'm still unsure how to use these functions to convert these ip addresses in place.

Any help on how I can implement this.

Comment: have you tried your proposed solution? does it not work for some reason? if not, can you provide the traceback? apply should work the same way in dask.dataframe - you may need to provide the `meta` argument to [`dask.dataframe.Series.apply`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.Series.apply.html), which could be as simple as `meta=("IP Add Src", int)`

Answer (score 1):

With Dask using [dask.dataframe.Series.apply](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.Series.apply.html) and the [treuss](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73638859/9302488) proposed method to evaluate IP address:

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
from functools import reduce

df = pd.DataFrame({'ip': ['9.166.0.1', '9.166.0.2', '9.166.0.3', '9.166.0.4', '9.166.0.5'],
                   'port': [80, 81, 82, 83, 84]})
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, 2)

def strip_to_int(str_ip):
    arr_ip = str_ip.split('.')
    if len(arr_ip)==4:
        return reduce(lambda x,y: x<<8|int(y), arr_ip, 0)
    return None

series_int_ip = ddf.ip.apply(strip_to_int, meta=ddf.ip)
ddf.assign(ip=series_int_ip)
```

result:

```
         ip     port
0   161873921   80
1   161873922   81
2   161873923   82
3   161873924   83
4   161873925   84
```

Answer (score -1):

The correct way to convert an IPv4-Address to a 32bit integer value is to "left shift" each octet by the appropriate number of bits, i.e. 24 for the first, 16 for the second and 8 for the third octet, and build the sum (or binary or) of the four resulting numbers:

```
from functools import reduce
ipAddress = '149.17.12.8'
ipAddressAsInt = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, [int(b)<<(8*(3-a)) for a,b in enumerate(ipAddress.split('.'))])
```

The expression in the code builds the 32bit value for each octet by using left-shift operator `<<` on the octet value `a` with an argument that is built from the position of the octet `b` returned by enumerate.
`reduce` than uses a simple lambda function to add the values. Note that `lambda x,y: x|y` also works and would technically actually be more correct.

Of course you could also do the left-shift directly in the lambda function, but imho this makes it less readable:

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x|int(y[1])<<(8*(3-y[0])), enumerate(ipAddress.split('.')), 0)
```

**Update**: A more readable version is this:

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x<<8|int(y), ipAddress.split('.'), 0)
```

Start with value 0, then for each octet in the IP-Address, left shift the current value by 8 and add the current octet.

To apply this to a dataframe column, use map as opposed to apply (check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36213383/pandas-dataframe-how-to-apply-function-to-a-specific-column)).

Small test/proof-of-concept:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'sourceHost': ['luke', 'leia', 'bb8'],
...                    'sourceIp': ['10.24.53.128', '10.24.125.44', '10.24.133.253'],
...                    'destHost': ['vader', 'palpatin', 'keylo'],
...                    'destIp': ['10.25.88.124', '10.25.230.12', '10.25.240.1']})
>>> df
  sourceHost       sourceIp  destHost        destIp
0       luke   10.24.53.128     vader  10.25.88.124
1       leia   10.24.125.44  palpatin  10.25.230.12
2        bb8  10.24.133.253     keylo   10.25.240.1
>>> df['sourceIp'] = df['sourceIp'].map(lambda ip: reduce(lambda x,y: x<<8|int(y), ip.split('.'), 0))
>>> df
  sourceHost   sourceIp  destHost        destIp
0       luke  169358720     vader  10.25.88.124
1       leia  169377068  palpatin  10.25.230.12
2        bb8  169379325     keylo   10.25.240.1
>>> df['destIp'] = df['destIp'].map(lambda ip: reduce(lambda x,y: x<<8|int(y), ip.split('.'), 0))
>>> df
  sourceHost   sourceIp  destHost     destIp
0       luke  169358720     vader  169433212
1       leia  169377068  palpatin  169469452
2        bb8  169379325     keylo  169472001
```

Comment: Thanks for info. However the issue I'm facing is how to actually convert these IP addresses within the dask dataframe.

Comment: I don't know dask, but in pandas you would typically do `df['IP Add Src'] = df['IP Add Src'].map(lambda ip: reduce(lambda x,y: x<<8|int(y), ip.split('.'), 0))`