# Apply function to each cell in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, apply

I have a dataframe that may look like this:

```
A        B        C
foo      bar      foo bar
bar foo  foo      bar
```

I want to look through every element of each row (or every element of each column) and apply the following function to get the subsequent dataframe:

```py
def foo_bar(x):
    return x.replace('foo', 'wow')
```

After applying the function, my dataframe will look like this:

```
A        B        C
wow      bar      wow bar
bar wow  wow      bar
```

Is there a simple one-liner that can apply a function to each cell?

This is a simplistic example so there may be an easier way to execute this specific example other than applying a function, but what I am really asking about is how to apply a function in every cell within a dataframe.

Answer (score 233, accepted):

You can use [`applymap()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) which is concise for your case.

```
df.applymap(foo_bar)

#     A       B       C
#0  wow     bar wow bar
#1  bar wow wow     bar
```

Another option is to vectorize your function and then use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method:

```
import numpy as np
df.apply(np.vectorize(foo_bar))
#     A       B       C
#0  wow     bar wow bar
#1  bar wow wow     bar
```

Comment: [Difference between map, applymap and apply methods in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19798153/395857)

Answer (score 3):

I guess you could use `np.vectorize`:

```
>>> df[:] = np.vectorize(foo_bar)(df)
>>> df
       A    B    C
foo  bar  wow  bar
bar  wow  wow  bar
>>>
```

This might be quicker, since it's using `numpy`.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Note: The original version of this answer referred to `applymap` but since pandas 2.1.0, that method has been renamed to `map`, so the answer was edited to reflect that change. Every point made in this answer applies to `applymap` as well.</sub>

Expanding on [Psidom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39476023/19123103), if the function you define accepts additional arguments, then you can pass them along using kwargs. For example, to toggle `repl` of `foo_bar()` in the OP:

```py
def foo_bar(x, bar=''):
    return x.replace('foo', bar)

df.map(foo_bar, bar='haha')
```

---

One of the common cases where `map` is especially useful is string operations (as in the OP). Since string operations in pandas are not optimized, a loop often performs better than vectorized operations especially if there are many operations. For example, for the following simple task of replacing values in a frame (with 1mil rows) using a condition, `map` is 2 times faster than an equivalent vectorized pandas code. The following test was run using pandas 2.2.1, numpy 1.26.3 on Python 3.11.5.

```py
def foo_bar(x):
    return x.replace('foo', 'wow') if len(x)>3 else x + ' this'

df = pd.DataFrame([['foo', 'bar', 'foo bar'], ['bar foo', 'foo', 'bar']]*500000, columns=[*'ABC'])

%timeit df.map(foo_bar)
# 1.25 s ± 109 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit df.apply(lambda x: np.where(x.str.len()>3, x.str.replace('foo', 'wow'), x + ' this'))
# 2.56 s ± 57.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

In current versions of Pandas, [applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) is deprecated (since version 2.1.0). You can use [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.map.html) instead:

```
df.applymap(foo_bar)
```