# How to round Float values in a same column that contains also Float number and Nan or None value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

In a DF, I have a column that contains `float`, `str`, `None` and `nan` values.

I would like to round only the `float` values without affecting the others. I tried to use a mask to access only the `float` values, but did not succeed.

I would prefer it if the solution could use native `pandas` functions instead of iteration.

Sample of my data:

```
 index      Column A         Column B   
 1          57:24.1          98.67799997
 2          57:24.1          58.67799997
 3          57:53.8          95.66000009
 4          358:23.4         210.68099999
 5          None             35.10
 6          25.06778         None
 7          99999.565656     Abc
 8          abc              None
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this - it will check if the value is a float, if yes it will round to 1, else do nothing:

```
df["Column B"].apply(lambda x: round(x,1) if isinstance(x,float) else x)
```

Or if you want to apply this function to every cell in the dataframe:

```
df.applymap(lambda x: round(x,1) if isinstance(x,float) else x)
```

See also: [Apply function to each cell in DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39475978/apply-function-to-each-cell-in-dataframe)

Comment: unfortunately, the first solution you proposed me returned me the Column B but not rounded & the second solution returned me the full DF without no changes (not rounded)

Comment: try replacing `float` with `np.float64`. It basically needs to be the exact type of float that you have in your dataframe.

Comment: the first solution you gave did not change the output

Comment: the second returned me : AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'applymap'

Comment: can i check that "df" is a dataframe with more than 1 column?

Answer (score 0):

How about trying this. Might be a bit expensive but worth trying

```
df['Column B'] = [round(val,2) for val in df['column B'] if type(val)==float]
```