# 'pandas' has no attribute 'to_float'

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, svm, text-classification

### I'm testing my data using the SVM Classifier. And my dataset is in a form of text and I'm trying to transform it into float.

I have data that may look like this:
[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1JLl.png)

---

## Transform as float

```
df.columns = df('columns').str.rstrip('%').astype('float') / 100.0


TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-74921537411d> in <module>
      1 # Transform as float
----> 2 df.columns = df('columns').str.rstrip('%').astype('float') / 100.0
      3 

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

Comment: `df('columns')` should be `df(['columns'])`?

Comment: I already changed it to:
df(['columns']) = df(['columns']).str.rstrip('%').astype('float') / 100.0

And I get:
  File "<ipython-input-70-f6892f00e443>", line 2
    df(['columns']) = df(['columns']).str.rstrip('%').astype('float') / 100.0
    ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call

Comment: i think you need [Apply function to each cell in DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39475978/apply-function-to-each-cell-in-dataframe)

Comment: It doesn't work like this, you need to learn the basics of text representation in ML, like one-hot encoding.

Comment: you write wrong code, please be careful

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it is impossible to convert `text` to `float`. In your dataset, it seems that all the columns have text values, and not sure if the value can be numbers by using `rstrip('%')` (because the values are too long, so truncated in the image).

If the values of a columns can be numbers by using `rstrip('%')`, then you can convert it. In addition, you are using `()`, not `[]` for the dataframe. Because you are using`df(...'), it looks like a function call. You can do what you want if the values of a columns is numbers, as follows:

```
df['columns'] = df['columns'].str.rstrip('%').astype('float') / 100.0
```

Here is a full code sample:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'column_name': ['111%', '222%'],
})
# df looks like:
#  columns
#0    111%
#1    222%

df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].str.rstrip('%').astype('float') / 100.0

print(df)
#   columns
#0     1.11
#1     2.22
```

Comment: `columns` as a column name is bad. the OP wants to convert all columns, actually.

Comment: @LeiYang That's right, but I wanted to edit the askers' code with minimum change.