# Create feature matrix from Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matrix

I would like to transform a dataframe into a feature matrix (actually, I'm not sure it is called a feature matrix).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Car': ['Audi', 'Toyota', 'Chrysler', 'Toyota', 'Chrysler', 'Chrysler'], 
                   'Color': ['red', 'red', 'blue', 'silver', 'blue', 'silver']})
```

```
    Car         Color
0   Audi            red
1   Toyota          red
2   Chrysler    blue
3   Toyota          silver
4   Chrysler    blue
5   Chrysler    silver
```

I would like to create a matrix with cars and colors as index and columns where a `True`, or 1 shows a possible combination like follows:

```
    Color   Audit   Chrysler  Toyota
0   blue    0   1     0
1   red 1   0     1
2   silver  0   1     1
```

I can create a matrix and then iterate over the rows and enter the values, but this takes quite long. Is there a better way to create this matrix?

Kind regards,
Stephan

Comment: Use `pd.crosstab` my friend: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) would seem to apply here:

```
df.pivot_table(index="Car", columns="Color", aggfunc=len)
```

Which gives:

```
Color       blue    red     silver
Car         
Audi        NaN     1.0     NaN
Chrysler    2.0     NaN     1.0
Toyota      NaN     1.0     1.0
```

You specify the vertical component as the index column (Car), and the horizontal one as the columns component (Color), then provide a function to fill the cells (len).

Then, to nuance it a little, you could use fillna() to "paint" the empty cells with zeros. And apply a logical test to show which ones are "possible"

e.g.

```
df.pivot_table(index="Car", columns="Color", aggfunc=len).fillna(0)>0
```

Which gives:

```
Color       blue    red     silver
Car         
Audi        False   True    False
Chrysler    True    False   True
Toyota      False   True    True
```

And as a final bit of polish, having learned about it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39475978/apply-function-to-each-cell-in-dataframe), you could run an `applymap` to get your 0,1 output:

```
(df.pivot_table(index="Car", columns="Color", aggfunc=len).fillna(0)>0).applymap(lambda x : 1 if x==True else 0)
```

Giving:

```
Color       blue    red     silver
Car         
Audi        0       1       0
Chrysler    1       0       1
Toyota      0       1       1
```

Finally, this process is sometimes referred to in the literature as [One Hot Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot) and there are some cool implementations such as [this one from sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) in case your investigations lead you in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

In extension to Thomas's answer below code should give exactly what you desire in the output

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Car': ['Audi', 'Toyota', 'Chrysler', 'Toyota', 'Chrysler', 'Chrysler'], 
                   'Color': ['red', 'red', 'blue', 'silver', 'blue', 'silver']})

output = (df.pivot_table(index="Car", columns="Color", aggfunc=len).fillna(0).T > 0).astype(int)
print(output)

Car     Audi  Chrysler  Toyota
Color                         
blue       0         1       0
red        1         0       1
silver     0         1       1
```