# Override default True == 1, False == 0 behavior

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean-operations

I have dataframes that can contain a mix of booleans and integers, and I'd like to be able to do things like `df_1 == df_2.loc[0,0]`, and guarantee that if `df_2.loc[0,0]` is 1 that it won't match `True` values in `df_1`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "I have dataframes that can contain a mix of booleans and integers"? What dtypes? object?

Comment: The dataframes are formed from csv data which will contain strings, ints, floats, bools, etc in unknown columns - so the dtypes aren't really known, it's whatever `read_csv` decides

Comment: A single column is always a single datatype.  You can't mix booleans and ints within a single column.

Comment: Dataframes _do_ have fixed dtypes. What are the dtypes of the dataframes you're working with?

Comment: Perhaps you should show us an example of the data you're using.

Comment: Just as a note, sometimes a data cleaning step is useful - i.e., converting `0,1,'yes','no','true','false','off','on','oui','non'` and all your other mixed up values to clean booleans.

Comment: @Brian61354270 I don't know the OP's data, but you can easily create this with `df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [True, 1, False, 0]})`. The dtype is `dtype('O')`.

Comment: @TimRoberts See my above comment.

Comment: If you print the df, it shows `True` and `1` in the first two rows. But `df['col'] == 1` is True in both rows.

Comment: @OCa [Please don't change code functionality/conventions in the question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260245/4518341)

Comment: Are you talking about bool and int in one column, like Barmar showed, or some bool columns, some int columns? An example would help a lot; check out [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Answer (score 1):

Pre-processing your data to avoid collisions between varied datatypes is better practice. But assuming you cannot separate integers from booleans in your dataframes, then enhance `==` with boolean detection:

```py
def BoolProofCompare(a, b):
    '''Override default True == 1, False == 0 behavior'''
    return a==b and isinstance(a, bool)==isinstance(b, bool)

BoolProofCompare(1, True)  # False
BoolProofCompare(0, False)  # False
BoolProofCompare(1, 1)  # True
BoolProofCompare(False, False)  # True
# and so on and so forth
```

Now, I gather that what you request is **cell by cell comparison** of a single value, e.g. `df_2[0][0]`, with each element in a dataframe, e.g. `df_1`, with `True==1` and `False==0` equalities disabled. In that case, use [applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) to [broadcast the above comparison to every cell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39475978/12846804):

```py
# my example of input dataframe
df
    col1  col2
0   True     1
1      1     2
2  False     3
3      0     4

df.applymap(lambda x : BoolProofCompare(x, True))
    col1   col2
0   True  False
1  False  False
2  False  False
3  False  False

df.applymap(lambda x : BoolProofCompare(x, False))
    col1   col2
0  False  False
1  False  False
2   True  False
3  False  False

df.applymap(lambda x : BoolProofCompare(x, 1))
    col1   col2
0  False   True
1   True  False
2  False  False
3  False  False

df.applymap(lambda x : BoolProofCompare(x, 0))
    col1   col2
0  False  False
1  False  False
2  False  False
3   True  False
```

I suppose it would be more convenient to encapsulate the enhanced comparison inside a new function, like this:

```py
def BoolProofCompare_df(df, a):
    '''
    Compare single value *a* with dataframe *df*, cell by cell, 
    with True==1 and False==0 equalities disabled.
    '''
    return df.applymap(lambda x : BoolProofCompare(x, a))
```

Answer (score 0):

See @OCa's answer for the `BoolProofCompare` function. An alternative implementation which also makes `0` (int) different from `0.0` (float):

```
def BoolProofCompare(a, b):
    return a == b and type(a) == type(b)
```

The reason why just `return a == b` doesn't work is that in Python `True == 1` and `True == 1.0`.