# Creating new column in pandas df populated by True,False depending on whether a float column is a whole number (`float.is_integer`)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas `df` where `df['value']` is a series of floats.

- Some of the floats will be whole numbers (like 25.0). I want to create a new column, `df['is_it_whole'][i]` with values `1` (or `True`) is the corresponding `df['value'][i]` is a whole number, `0` or `False` otherwise.
- I know I can do a for loop, but I am wondering if there is any trick I can use to do it fast (I have a large df).
- I tried using `df['is_it_whole'] = df['value'].is_integer()` but pandas series do not support the `is_integer` method, I am looking for something similar that would work.

Suggestions?

Comment: Your question boils down to "How can I call the Python method `float.is_integer` on a pandas series df['value']?" or in general ***How can I call Python(/numpy/whatever) method type.X on a pandas series `col`?***, to which the general answer is ***`col.apply/map(type.X)`***, and  no you generally don't need to declare a lambda (for a 1-arg function X).

Answer (score 7):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 1], ['B', 2.5], ['C', 3.0], ['D', 3.2]], columns=['label', 'value'])
df['is_it_whole'] = df['value'].map(lambda x: x.is_integer())
df

  label  value is_it_whole
0     A    1.0        True
1     B    2.5       False
2     C    3.0        True
3     D    3.2       False
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more pandastic to use `apply` here instead of `map`?

Comment: @lanery As pointed out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19798528/304209), `apply` "works on a row / column basis of a DataFrame", while `map` works element-wise on a Series (note the examples there). I personally find it more intuitive to use `map` for a column, but YMMV.

Comment: You don't need to declare a lambda function. Just directly do `df['value'].map(float.is_integer)`

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
df['is_it_whole'] = (df['value'].round() == df['value'])
```

Or to take into account float number inaccuracy:

```
tol = 0.001
df['is_it_whole'] = ((df['value'].round() - df['value']).abs() < tol)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to declare a lambda function. Just directly apply `df['value'].map(float.is_integer)`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 1], ['B', 2.5], ['C', 3.0], ['D', 3.2]], columns=['label', 'value'])
df['is_it_whole'] = df['value'].map(float.is_integer)

>>> df
  label  value  is_it_whole
0     A    1.0         True
1     B    2.5        False
2     C    3.0         True
3     D    3.2        False
```

Answer (score 0):

This applies is_integer to each element in the series:

```
df['is_it_whole'] = df['value'].apply(lambda x: x.is_integer())
```

Comment: You don't need to declare a lambda function. Just directly do `df['value'].map(float.is_integer)`