# How do I extract the list inside a string in Python?

Tags: python

I imported a CSV using Pandas and one column was read in with string entries. Examining the entries for this Series (column), I see that they should actually be lists. For example:

```
df['A'] = pd.Series(['["entry11"]', '["entry21","entry22"]', '["entry31","entry32"]'])
```

I would like to extract the list elements from the strings. So far, I've tried the following chain:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].replace("'",'',regex=True).
                  replace('\[','',regex=True).
                  replace('\]','',regex=True).
                  str.split(",")
```

(all on one line, of course).

and this gives me back my desired list elements in one column.

- ['"entry11"']
- ['"entry21", "entry22"']
- ['"entry31", "entry32"']

My question: Is there a more efficient way of doing this? This seems like a lot of strain for something that should be a little easier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can ["apply"](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) the [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to the series:

```
In [8]: from ast import literal_eval

In [9]: df['A'] = df['A'].apply(literal_eval)

In [10]: df
Out[10]: 
                    A
0           [entry11]
1  [entry21, entry22]
2  [entry31, entry32]
```

There is also `map()` and `applymap()` - here is a topic where the differences are discussed:

- [Difference between map, applymap and apply methods in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19798153/771848)

Comment: Thanks! I knew `ast.literal_eval` would do it, but I don't know pandas so I didn't know you can map that easily over the series

Comment: @AdamSmith generally, you want to avid `.apply` for performance reasons because it just wraps a for-loop in Python, although, in some cases you don't have a choice.

Comment: Thanks! That answers my question!! As a side question (if that's possible) what if some of the entries are pure strings rather than lists inside of strings, like "entry" rather than "[entry]'?

Comment: @Chris sure, if the `"entry"` is enclosed into quotes, then `literal_eval` would be able to safely evaluate it (the solution would work as is). If not, you might need a custom function where you can handle possible `ValueError`s thrown by `literal_eval()` and return, for example, the same unevaluated string.