# How to convert a string in the list to list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

Below is my list

```
l =['[37i9dQZF1DX5, 37i9dQZF1DWTR, 37i9dQZF1DX0s5]']
```

I want to convert it into

```
l =[37i9dQZF1DX5, 37i9dQZF1DWTR, 37i9dQZF1DX0s5]
```

I tried using eval but it doesn't work!

Comment: You can't have that result, because string should be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: Yes true, i am stuck with thus.I tried  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41945880/how-do-i-extract-the-list-inside-a-string-in-python but it doesn't work as i dont have a string inside

Comment: Look at [str.strip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) for removing the brackets and [str.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) for splitting the remaining string into a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ca do this,

```
l =['[37i9dQZF1DX5, 37i9dQZF1DWTR, 37i9dQZF1DX0s5]']
l2 = l[0].replace("[","").replace("]","").split(", ")
```

Which will give you the following as the content of l2

```
['37i9dQZF1DX5', '37i9dQZF1DWTR', '37i9dQZF1DX0s5']
```

Comment: @Wups No idea! My brain went straight to a comprehension this morning. I'll get some caffeine and edit!

Comment: thanks for the solution! I was using regex expression to remove the chars 


Answer (score 0):

If the contents of the list are strings, you can use json

```
import json
l = '["37i9dQZF1DX5", "37i9dQZF1DWTR", "37i9dQZF1DX0s5"]'#I added " to make strings
print (json.loads (l))
type (json.loads (l))
```

The output will be:

```
["37i9dQZF1DX5", "37i9dQZF1DWTR", "37i9dQZF1DX0s5"]
<class 'list'>
```