# Apply function to dataset to replace dynamically

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas which is 6x3 and the columns represent times.

I want to replace values on conditions:

```
def substituteMin(x,n,c,k):
    if x < (1 - c)^n+sqrt(k):
        x = (1 - c)^n+sqrt(k)
    else:
        pass
    return x
df1 = df.apply(lambda x: compareMin(x, x.name))
print (df1)
```

where c and k are constant. And n is the column name.
It gives me the error

> "ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', u'occurred at index 1.0')"

I tried to look at replace function but they did not work.

Comment: > "I have a **panda** which is 6x3 and the columns represent times" -

What do you feed it?

Comment: what are `n,c,k`? Are they constants?

Comment: The error is that you are doing a comparison on a series and returning a single value.  Pandas/Python doesn't know what single value to return if part of the series is True and part of the series is False.  Hence the "ambiguous" exception.  You can use function like all() or any() to reduce the series True/False to one value.

Comment: I think you need `applymap`.

Comment: And what if I want to do it element by element?

Answer (score 0):

Here I have simplified your code.

```
def func(x,n=0,c=1,k=2):
    if x < (1 - c)^n+sqrt(k):
        x = (1 - c)^n+sqrt(k)
    return x
df1 = df.applymap(lambda x: func(x))
print (df1)
```

Modifications:

1. [`applymap`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798153/difference-between-map-applymap-and-apply-methods-in-pandas) to replace element-wise.
2. Function names were inconsistent: substituteMin, compareMin.
3. In the function (substituteMin), constant variables (n,c,k) can be set in the function only.

(There is plenty to comment and edit in your question. Currently, I don't have privileges.)

Comment: Thanks but how can I pass n to be the column name? I would do "lambda x: func(x, x.name)" but it does not work

Comment: that's because `x` would not have have an attribute `name`. to accomplish your objective I guess you should simply iterate over rows and columns (nested). eg. 
    `for col in df: 
        for row in df.index: 
             y=func(df.loc[row,col],col)`
Note: go to new line after `:`s. it's not a one liner like `lambda`.