# Python Pandas filtering; TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame looking like this:

```
ID  Instrument  Units   Price   Status
165  WTICO_USD     -1   60.264  OPEN
169  WTICO_USD     -1   60.274  OPEN
173  WTICO_USD      1   54.284  OPEN
185  BCO_USD        1   60.124  OPEN
```

If I write the following, I get what I expect:

```
DF[(DF.Instrument=='WTICO_USD')]
```

And same with this:

```
DF[(DF.Instrument=='WTICO_USD')&(DF.ID==165)]
```

However, if I try to filter further, as in this, I get no rows:

```
DF[(DF.Instrument=='WTICO_USD')&(DF['Units']==-1)]
```

Same with

```
DF[(DF.Instrument=='WTICO_USD')&(DF.Units=='-1')]
```

However, this gives an error:

```
DF[(DF.Instrument=='WTICO_USD')&(DF['Units']>-1)]
```

> TypeError: cannot convert the series to class 'int'

So, I try this and get another error:

```
DF.Units.applymap(int)
```

> 'Series' object has no attribute 'applymap'

So, since I select all values in the unit column, I get a series that I cannot convert. But why do I also get so when I try this?

```
DF[(DF.Instrument=='WTICO_USD')&(int(DF['Units'])>-1)]
```

> cannot convert the series to class 'int'

How can I filter on all rows that are `Instrument == WTICO_USD` and have a `Units < 0` ?

Comment: No, those are entered as separate commands, and hence, the first should not impact the second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `DF.Units = DF.Units.map(int)` or `DF.Units = DF.Units.astype(int)`. From there your filters should work.

Just for reference [Difference between map, applymap and apply methods in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798153/difference-between-map-applymap-and-apply-methods-in-pandas)
, gives a great explanation of the differences between `apply`, `applymap`, and `map`. You may notice that under the definitions of the methods `applymap` would be nonsensical on a series.

Comment: You have to assign the output of the call to `astype` to `DF.Units` otherwise the values are unchanged.