# How to convert np.int64 into python int64 for PandasSeries?

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, numpy, types

I try to insert data from pandas DataFrame into the PostgreSQL table,

table that a try to insert looks like:

```
city_id date        forecast
5       29.05.2019  0
1       29.05.2019  0
151     29.05.2019  0
55      29.05.2019  0
...
```

**types:**

- `city_id` - `numpy.int64`
- `date` - `datetime.date`
- `forecast` - `numpy.int64`

And the **block of code**, that inserting data to db:

```
        with psycopg2.connect(f"host='{hostname}' \
                              dbname='{database}' \
                              user='{username}' \
                              password='{password}'") as connection:
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                connection.set_client_encoding('UTF8')
                for i in df_with_new_one.index:
                    date = df_with_new_one['date'][i]
                    city_id = df_with_new_one['city_id'][i]
                    value = df_with_new_one['forecast'][i]

                    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO forecast \
                    (city_id, computed_time, date, value) \
                    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)", (city_id, now, date, value))
```

Where `now` is time saved as `datetime.datetime.now()`

**And i get** *ProgrammingError*:

```
    ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'numpy.int64'
```

I checked **type** `type(df_with_new_one['forecast'][0])` type is `numpy.int64`

So I get that PostreSQL can read only pythonic `int` and `float`, and the first thing i've tried was converting `np.int64` into simple `int` with:

- `tolist()`
- `pd.to_numeric()`
- `int()` for `((int(city_id), now, date, int(value))`
- `.astype(int)`
- `.value.astype('int')`

**Upd.:**

- `city_id = int(df_with_new_one['city_id'][i])`
  `value = int(df_with_new_one['forecast'][i])`

Unfortunately **none of them works** for me

When I tried `int()` I get another error:

```
    TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

Answers that **i found**, but no one of them helped me:

- [psycopg2: can't adapt type 'numpy.int64'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50626058/psycopg2-cant-adapt-type-numpy-int64)
- [ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'numpy.ndarray'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39564755/programmingerror-psycopg2-programmingerror-cant-adapt-type-numpy-ndarray)
- [Python TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'> when trying to do math on dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41000428/python-typeerror-cannot-convert-the-series-to-class-int-when-trying-to-do-m)
- [Python Pandas filtering; TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48120611/python-pandas-filtering-typeerror-cannot-convert-the-series-to-class-int?rq=1)

Are there **any other methods** to change type of values?

Comment: The problems seems to be that you try to push a non-scalar (a Pandas series) as a field of your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in wrong indexation:

- first index was from 83 to 1161 and after 1161, where should've been 1161, was 83 again and next values were 83 + 1 etc.

Thus, problem was solved by `.reset_index()`

`df_with_new_one.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)`

Thanks you all for answers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.ndarray.item()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html)

```
type(np.arange(1)[0])
# numpy.int64
type(np.arange(1)[0].item())
# int
```

Comment: Should i do it like this: ```df_with_new_one['forecast'] = df_with_new_one['forecast'].apply(lambda x: x.item())``` ?

Answer (score 0):

First, your method is not very efficient because you repeatedly call `cursor.execute` instead of calling `cursor.executemany`.

But as you pass individuals values, it is easy to convert them just in time:

```
            ...
            for i in df_with_new_one.index:
                date = df_with_new_one['date'][i]
                city_id = int(df_with_new_one['city_id'][i])
                value = int(df_with_new_one['forecast'][i])
            ...
```

Comment: I tried, but get another error: ```TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>``` 
I'll read about ```cursor.executemany```, thank you!

Comment: @Doppie: Are you sure you have correctly copied my code? `df_with_new_one['city_id']` is certainly a `Series`, but `df_with_new_one['city_id'][i]` should not.

Comment: Yes, except ```date = int(df_with_new_one['date'][i])```, because ```data``` is ```datetime.date```. Thus ```int()``` for ```city_id``` and ```value```

Comment: @Doppie: My bad. I had put one `int()` in the wrong place. Should be better that way.