# pandas dataframe apply lambda if else erro

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I am trying to apply lambda with if-else condition on a pandas df
df looks like following:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 <---column names
None None None col4 <---column values in str
col1 None None None
None col2 None None



df_twitter_archive_master[['col1','col2','col3','col4']].apply(lambda x: x=0 if x=='None' else x=1)
```

basically, it should replace 'None' value with 0 and else with 1
but I keep getting this error

```
df_twitter_archive_master[['col1','col2','col3','col4']].apply(lambda x: x=0 if x=='None' else x=1)

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

^ is under x=1

what am i doing wrong? ?

Comment: Can you post  a sample dataframe with expected outputs?

Comment: ok just updated

Comment: While the rest of the answers get you the result, your problem came from the syntax `x=0` and `x=1`.  Within your lambda you shouldn't be assigning values.  Just `lambda x: 0 if x == 'None' else 1` will suffice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIUC

```
df.replace('None',np.nan).notnull().astype(int)
Out[31]: 
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     0     0     0     1
1     1     0     0     0
2     0     1     0     0
```

Base on your lambda method

```
df.applymap(lambda x: 0 if x=='None' else 1)
Out[33]: 
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     0     0     0     1
1     1     0     0     0
2     0     1     0     0
```

Comment: what is difference  between .apply and .applymap ??

Comment: @ikel you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798153/difference-between-map-applymap-and-apply-methods-in-pandas

Comment: i see, i just tested with 'else 1' it works, but when I remove else 1, it got same syntax error?

Comment: @ikel `DataFrame.apply` passes each column (default, axis=0) or row (axis=1) to the provided function. `applymap` operates on the individual elements within the rows and columns. `Series.apply` operates on the elements of the series. `Series.map` and `Series.apply` are subtly different in the general case, but are effective the same when passed a callable function.

Answer (score 5):

Let's try:

```
(df != 'None').astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     0     0     0     1
1     1     0     0     0
2     0     1     0     0
```