# Mapping values inside pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, data-science

I used the code below to map the 2 values inside S column to 0 but it didn't work. Any suggestion on how to solve this?
N.B : I want to implement an external function inside the map.

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({
   'Age': [30,40,50,60,70,80],
   'Sex': ['F','M','M','F','M','F'],
   'S'  : [1,1,2,2,1,2]
 })
 def app(value):
     for n in df['S']:
         if n == 1:
             return 1
         if n == 2:
             return 0
 df["S"] = df.S.map(app)
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use **`apply`**, simply use **`loc`** to assign the values:

```
df.loc[df.S.eq(2), 'S'] = 0

   Age Sex  S
0   30   F  1
1   40   M  1
2   50   M  0
3   60   F  0
4   70   M  1
5   80   F  0
```

If you need a more performant option, use **`np.select`**. This is also more scalable, as you can always add more conditions:

```
df['S'] = np.select([df.S.eq(2)], [0], 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `eq` to create a boolean series and conver that boolean series to int with `astype`:

```
df['S'] = df['S'].eq(1).astype(int)
```

OR

```
df['S'] = (df['S'] == 1).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   Age Sex  S
0   30   F  1
1   40   M  1
2   50   M  0
3   60   F  0
4   70   M  1
5   80   F  0
```

Comment: Hmm, this is much faster than assigning via `loc`

Comment: @user3483203 you can try mask , should be faster :-) `df.S.mask(df.S>1,0)
`

Comment: Yep, much faster, I need to use `mask` more :D

Answer (score 1):

You're close but you need a few corrections. Since you want to use a function, remove the `for` loop and replace `n` with `value`. Additionally, use `apply` instead of `map`. `Apply` operates on the entire column at once. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19798528/9435107) for how to properly use `apply` vs `applymap` vs `map`

```
def app(value):
    if value == 1:
        return 1
    elif value == 2:
        return 0
df['S'] = df.S.apply(app)
   Age Sex  S
0   30   F  1
1   40   M  1
2   50   M  0
3   60   F  0
4   70   M  1
5   80   F  0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
import numpy as np

df['S'] = np.where(df['S'] == 2, 0, df['S'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only wish to change values equal to 2, you can use `pd.DataFrame.loc`:

```
df.loc[df['S'] == 0, 'S'] = 0
```

`pd.Series.apply` is not recommend and this is just a thinly veiled, inefficient loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could use .replace as follows:
df["S"] = df["S"].replace([2], 0)
This will replace all of 2 values to 0 in one line

Answer (score 0):

Go with vectorize numpy operation:

```
df['S'] = np.abs(df['S'] - 2)
```

and stand yourself out from competitions in interviews and SO answers :)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>>df = pd.DataFrame({'Age':[30,40,50,60,70,80],'Sex': 
 ['F','M','M','F','M','F'],'S': 
 [1,1,2,2,1,2]})


>>> def app(value):
        return 1 if value == 1 else 0 
    # or app = lambda value : 1 if value == 1 else 0

>>> df["S"] = df["S"].map(app)

>>> df 
   Age  S Sex
      Age  S Sex
   0   30  1   F
   1   40  1   M
   2   50  0   M
   3   60  0   F
   4   70  1   M
   5   80  0   F
```