# Using Dataframes style.apply for Highlighting based on comparative values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

In my code I am using df.style.applymap() to render HTML onto my intranet Webpage.
I have the following Code which is working Well for me, (2 Columns are passed on to my function highlight_vals).

```
def highlight_vals(val, color='green', color1='red'):
        if val > 0.8:
            return 'background-color: %s' % color
        elif val < -0.9:
            return 'background-color: %s' % color1
        else:
            return ''
```

Now, I want to make a similar function (or ever use the current highlight_vals) in order to achieve Comparative Highlighting with the condition on the lines of:
 
   if ValinColumn1 > 0.25 * ValinColumn2: # (For same Row/Record)
    return 'background-color: %s' % color #Yellow/Highlights.

I am using the above function in my **views.py**:
httresp += df.style.applymap(highlight_vals,subset=[col1,col2])

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `apply(axis=1)` to iterate through rows:

```
def highlight_vals(row, cols=['A', 'B'], color='green'):
    a, b = cols
    styles = {col: '' for col in row.index}
    if row[a] > 0.25 * row[b]:
        styles[a] = 'background-color: %s' % color
        styles[b] = 'background-color: %s' % color
    return styles

df.style.apply(lambda x: highlight_vals(x, cols=['B', 'E']), axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You, I will test this out sometime today.

Comment: I checked this in detail, it appears to be Highlighting the wrong columns, Do we really need to use the Lambda here, the Pandas Documentation suggests otherwise.

Comment: It appears the cols is not working in the Function Highlight_vals

Comment: Well firstly I am able to same result as above using just apply(highlight_vals, axis=1),  i.e. I am Not using the Lambda

Comment: However with your original code and my code it still the Wrong column gets Highlighted , the condition itself is fine.

Comment: Thanks for the Help though, currently I am fine with this solution.

Comment: Just to be clear Your code as well as my revised code just Highlight the First column (after index col) in the DataFrame.. Thanks.

Comment: What is your `df.columns`?

Answer (score 0):

From this question:
[Difference between map, applymap and apply methods in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798153/difference-between-map-applymap-and-apply-methods-in-pandas)
I think what you need is the function apply. It can work on multiple columns.
You are using applymap which is oriented for the whole dataframe (but you go around that by selecting a column from your dataframe with df.style)

Here is a toy example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], columns=['A', 'B'])
>>> df['sum_A_B']=df.apply(lambda x: x['A'] + x['B'], axis=1)
>>> df
   A  B  sum_A_B
0  1  2        3
1  3  4        7
```