# Pandas: How to highlight a cell value based on a Z-score value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy, statsmodels

In my `df` below, I want to :

1. identify and flag the outliers  in `col_E` using z-scores
2. separately explain how to identify and flag the outliers using z-scores in two or more columns, for example `col_D` & `col_E`

See below for the dataset

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
  
# intialise data of lists
df = { 
         'col_A':['P0', 'P1', 'P2', 'P4', 'P5'],
         'col_B':[1,1,1,1,1],
         'col_C':[1,2,3,5,9],
         'col_D':[120.05, 181.90, 10.34, 153.10, 311.17],
        'col_E':[110.21, 191.12, 190.21, 12.00, 245.09 ],
        'col_F':[100.22,199.10, 191.13,199.99, 255.19],
        'col_G':[140.29, 291.07, 390.22, 245.09, 4122.62],
        
        }
  
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
  
# Print the output.
df
```

Desired: flag all outliers in `col_D` first and then `col_D` and `col_E` secondly (Note: In my image below `10.34` and `12.00` were randomly highlighted)

Q1

[image]

Attempt:

```
#Q1
exclude_cols = ['col_A','col_B','col_C','col_D','col_F','col_G']
include_cols = ['col_E'] # desired column

def flag_outliers(s, exclude_cols):
    if s.name in exclude_cols:
        print(s.name)
        return '' 
    else:
        s=df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df['col_E'])) > 3)] # not sure of this part of the code
        
        return ['background-color: yellow' if v else '' for v in indexes]

df.style.apply(lambda s: flag_outliers(s, exclude_cols), axis=1, subset=include_cols)



#Q2
exclude_cols = ['col_A','col_B','col_C','col_F','col_G']
include_cols = ['col_D','col_E'] # desired columns

def flag_outliers(s, exclude_cols):
    if s.name in exclude_cols:
        print(s.name)
        return '' 
    else:
        s=df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df['col_E'])) > 3)] # not sure of this part of the code
        
        return ['background-color: yellow' if v else '' for v in indexes]

df.style.apply(lambda s: flag_outliers(s, exclude_cols), axis=1, subset=include_cols)
```

Thanks!

Comment: `stats.zscore(df['col_D'])` and `stats.zscore(df['col_E'])` indicates NO OUTLIERS WITH `|z| > 3` EXISTS!

Comment: And, what do you mean by "z-scores in two or more columns"? Do you pool these values together as one sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the following meanings to demonstrate a broader range of usage.

- Q1 stands for calculating a single column
- Q2 stands for calculating over multiple columns pooled together.

If Q2 is meant to calculated on multiple columns separately, then you can simply loop your Q1 solution over multiple columns, which should be trivial so I will omit such situation here.

## Keys

- Q1 is quite straightforward as one can return a list of values by list comprehension.
- Q2 is a little bit complicated because the z-score would be applied over a DataFrame subset (i.e. `axis=None` must be used). According to the [official docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Building-styles), when applying style over a DataFrame, the returning object must also be a DataFrame with the same index and columns as the subset. This is what caused the reshaping and DataFrame construction artifacts.

## Single Column (Q1)

Note that `z=3` is lowered to `1.5` for demonstration purpose.
# desired column
include_cols = ['col_E']

```
# additional control
outlier_threshold = 1.5   # 3 won't work!
ddof = 0   # degree of freedom correction. Sample = 1 and population = 0.

def flag_outliers(s: pd.Series):
    outlier_mask = np.abs(stats.zscore(s, ddof=ddof)) > outlier_threshold
    # replace boolean values with corresponding strings
    return ['background-color: yellow' if val else '' for val in outlier_mask]

df.style.apply(flag_outliers, subset=include_cols)
```

**Result**

[image]

## Multiple Column Pooled (Q2, Assumed)

## Q2

```
include_cols = ['col_D', 'col_E']  # desired columns

outlier_threshold = 1.5
ddof = 0

def flag_outliers(s: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    outlier_mask = np.abs(stats.zscore(s.values.reshape(-1), axis=None, ddof=ddof)) > outlier_threshold
    # prepare the array of string to be returned
    arr = np.array(['background-color: yellow' if val else '' for val in outlier_mask], dtype=object).reshape(s.shape)
    # cast the array into dataframe
    return pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=s.columns, index=s.index)

df.style.apply(flag_outliers, axis=None, subset=include_cols)
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52528568/using-dataframes-style-apply-for-highlighting-based-on-comparative-values), just pass the condition of the score to a dict storing the background color of each column index.

```
include_cols = ['col_D', 'col_E']

def color_outliers_yellow(row, include, color='yellow', z_score = 1):
    
    styles = {col: '' for col in row.index}
    
    if row.name in include:
        
        scores = stats.zscore(list(row))
        
        scores = [(f'background-color: {color}' if score > z_score else '') for score in scores]
        
        return {k:v for k, v in zip(styles.keys(), scores)}
    
    else:
        
        return styles

df.style.apply(lambda x: color_outliers_yellow(x, include=include_cols), axis=0)
```

Results in:

[image]

Comment: I would love for someone to break down what this code is doing/how it works...   For my situation I want to replace the 'outliers' rather than highlight them.

Comment: @flashliquid do you mean replacing values? could you provide more context? It seems that styling approach would not be ideal for your case