# Replace values in pandas column with default value for missing keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, replace

I have multiple simple functions that need to be implemented on every row of certain columns of my dataframe. The dataframe is very like, 10 million+ rows. My dataframe is something like this:

```
Date      location   city        number  value
12/3/2018   NY       New York      2      500
12/1/2018   MN       Minneapolis   3      600
12/2/2018   NY       Rochester     1      800
12/3/2018   WA       Seattle       2      400
```

I have functions like these:

```
def normalized_location(row):
    if row['city'] == " Minneapolis":
        return "FCM"
    elif row['city'] == "Seattle":
        return "FCS"
    else:
        return "Other"
```

and then I use:

```
df['Normalized Location'] =df.apply (lambda row: normalized_location (row),axis=1)
```

This is extremely slow, how can I make this more efficient?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can make this BLAZING fast using `map` with a `defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda: 'Other')
d.update({"Minneapolis": "FCM", "Seattle": "FCS"})

df['normalized_location'] = df['city'].map(d)

print(df)
        Date location         city  number  value normalized_location
0  12/3/2018       NY     New York       2    500               Other
1  12/1/2018       MN  Minneapolis       3    600                 FCM
2  12/2/2018       NY    Rochester       1    800               Other
3  12/3/2018       WA      Seattle       2    400                 FCS
```

...to circumvent a `fillna` call, for performance reasons. This approach generalises to multiple replacements quite easily.

Comment: I can Google (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798153/difference-between-map-applymap-and-apply-methods-in-pandas), but can you briefly explain or link to an explanation for the `defaultdict(lambda: 'Other')` line? If the location is not in the `dict`, it gets set to `Other`?

Comment: @Evan You got it, when the key is not present, "Other" is returned by the dictionary.

Comment: This is really fast. Thank you!!

Comment: How would you do this if you needed to use regex instead of "Minneapolis" or "Seattle"?

Answer (score 5):

You might want to use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
conds = [df.city == 'Minneapolis', df.city == 'Seattle']
choices = ['FCM', 'FCS']

df['normalized_location'] = np.select(conds, choices, default='other')

>>> df
        Date location         city  number  value normalized_location
0  12/3/2018       NY     New York       2    500               other
1  12/1/2018       MN  Minneapolis       3    600                 FCM
2  12/2/2018       NY    Rochester       1    800               other
3  12/3/2018       WA      Seattle       2    400                 FCS
```

Comment: Learn something new every day +1

Comment: Just a small note, for each replacement, you will need to compute a separate mask.

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
map_ = {'Minneapolis':'FCM', 'Seattle':'FCS'}
df.loc[:,'city'] = df.loc[:,'city'].map(map_).fillna('Other')

print(df)
    Date      location  city    number  value
0  12/3/2018       NY  Other       2    500
1  12/1/2018       MN    FCM       3    600
2  12/2/2018       NY  Other       1    800
3  12/3/2018       WA    FCS       2    400
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a nested `np.where()`:

```
df['city'] = np.where(df['city']=='Minneapolis', 'FCM', np.where(df['city']=='Seattle', 'FCS', 'Other'))
```

Comment: This turns out to be faster than `np.select` for nesting depths upto 3.