# Using pandas to optimize the hashing applied on a Series

Tags: python, pandas, performance, hash

I have a function that hashes int values that exist in a `pd.DataFrame`'s column `some_id`. My problem is that at the end, I am forced to use a `pd.Series.apply` in order to use `md5(x).hexdigest()`. If the `apply(f)` is called on a dataframe of considerable row size, it will cause tremendous performance problems (time + memory), because function calls in python are horrendous. Therefore, if it is applied on 10 million rows... `OOM kill` is inevitable. (I have tried)

The following function does exactly what it should, the part to change is the one marked bellow the `#TODO`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from hashlib import md5
from pandas.api.types import is_numeric_dtype

def hash_some_id(data: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    # Remove all na and 0 values in order to encode the rest
    data_to_encode = data.copy()
    data_to_encode = data.replace(0, np.nan)
    data_to_encode.dropna(inplace=True)
    if is_numeric_dtype(data_to_encode.some_id):
        # Convert the int some_id to str and prepend 0 to it
        data_to_encode.some_id = "0" + data_to_encode.some_id.astype(str)
        # Encode to binary
        data_to_encode.some_id = data_to_encode.some_id.str.encode('ascii')

        # TODO : Optimize this
        #  This is inefficient as it is applied on each row of data. 
        #  Find a way to vectorize it
        encoded_data = data_to_encode.some_id.apply(lambda x : md5(x).hexdigest())

    return encoded_data
```

Comment: Did you try with `pd.Series.map` ?

Comment: @Siddharth Well, after reading about `map`,`apply` and `applymap`, I realise they operate in the same fashion? Row-wise application of a function. Is that true?

Comment: I am also not sure but you are operating on a series `data_to_encode.some_id`, that's why I suggested to use `pd.Series.map`. This should help for the difference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798153/difference-between-map-applymap-and-apply-methods-in-pandas. Apart from that I guess you may try https://dask.org/

Comment: @Siddarth : I thought about it, but I want to make sure I exhaust all possibilities of pandas before changing my code completely into `dask`