# Run a function for each row and create a new Column Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using geoprapy to to get locations via a URL. I have a URL column for my DataFrame. I am attempting to run a pre-built Geograpy function on each URL and create a new column of the locations on the DataFrame. So, I have tried (from other questions):

```py
hits['place'] = geograpy.get_place_context(url=hits.urls)

# and

hits['place'] = hits.apply(geograpy.get_place_context(url=hits.urls), axis=1))

# and

def getPlace(frame):
    urls = frame['urls']
    print(urls)
    frame['place'] = geograpy.get_place_context(url=urls)
    return frame

getPlace(hits)
```

Along with a few others. I keep getting

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Which I understand as that it is seeing URLs as a whole column and cannot run the function on the column? Doesn't really matter.

How can I run a function for every row in a dataframe and create a new column?

I expect my places to be a 'memory type object' I can reference later. I have part of this to work via:

```py
for url in urls:
    place = (geograpy.get_place_context(url=url))
    region = place.country_regions
```

However, later in the code, the iterations causes it to fall apart.

Answer (score 3):

pandas.apply function does exactly what you want, you just didn't pass the right argument.
You can see in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) that you need to pass a function, not the result of the function call.

So, just pass geograpy.get_place_context to apply like this -

```
hits['place'] = hits['urls'].apply(geograpy.get_place_context, axis=1)
```

Comment: The problem is that I have to pass the URL to the ```get_place_context``` function like so ```hits['place'] = hits.assign(geograpy.get_place_context(url=hits['url']))``` It does not register that URL

Comment: You don't have to pass the url manually. Apply passes the values in the column to your function.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `.apply()` over the `urls` column like:

```
hits['place'] = hits['urls'].apply(geograpy.get_place_context, axis=1)
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798153/difference-between-map-applymap-and-apply-methods-in-pandas) answer had helped find the distinction between different vectorization methods and their usage. Hope you find it useful too.

*Edit:* Since only one column is used to create another, `.apply()` over that column should work fine for you. `.apply()` is defined over a `DataFrame` as well as a `Series`.