# Is there a better way to iterate over every row of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've doing this iteration to execute a different function for each single value of a dataframe:

being xxx a 2-col dataframe

```
for i in range(1, len(xxx)):
row = xxx[i-1:i]
do_something(row['value1'])
do_something_else(row['value2'])
```

this works fine, but I've always wondered if is there some way to make the same operation more *readable*

Please answer with concepts or libraries that I should check

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas)

Comment: If you need to iterate over the rows of your data frame, you should seriously question whether a data frame is the best representation for your data.  Almost all uses are better solved by some form of vectorization: apply a function to all rows of the data frame (i.e. let the run-time system manage your iteration).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4],['A','B','C','D']]).T
df.columns=['A','B']
def func(X):
    return X**2
r=map(func, df['A'])
df['A']=pd.DataFrame(r)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a function along an axis of the DataFrame (rows or columns) with apply:

```
pandas.DataFrame.apply
```

```
DataFrame.apply(func, axis=0, raw=False, result_type=None, args=(), **kwds)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also try using a lambda function along with an apply method like this:

Let's say that you have a function that converts an element to a string and then capitalizes that string.

```
def capitalize(cell):
    return str(cell).capitalize()
```

You may then apply that function on every row for a chosen column.

```
df["Column"].apply(lambda x: capitalize(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

One potential solution is to [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)  regular `functions` or `lambda` functions to the columns of the dataframe, which is much more faster and efficient than a loop (e.g. `df.iterrows()`).

Here is summary of efficient dataframe/series manipulation methods based on an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798153/difference-between-map-applymap-and-apply-methods-in-pandas) :

- `map` works for Series **ONLY**
- `applymap` works for DataFrames **ONLY**
- `apply` works for **BOTH**

` Here is a toy example :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 2), columns=list('AB'))
print(df)

def square(x):
   return x**2

#mapping a lambda function
print('Result of mapping with a lambda function')
df['A'] = df['A'].map(lambda x : x**2)
print(df)

#mapping a regular function
print('Result of mapping with a regular function')
df['C']  =df['A'].map(square)
print(df)

#apply
print('Result of applymap a regular function')
df1 = df.applymap(square)
print(df1)


#apply
print('Result of applying with a regular function')
df2 = df.apply(square)
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
          A         B
0 -0.030899 -2.206942
1  0.080991  0.049431
2  1.190754 -0.101161
3  0.794870 -0.969503

Result of mapping with a lambda function
          A         B
0  0.000955 -2.206942
1  0.006560  0.049431
2  1.417894 -0.101161
3  0.631818 -0.969503

Result of mapping with a regular function
          A         B             C
0  0.000955 -2.206942  9.115775e-07
1  0.006560  0.049431  4.302793e-05
2  1.417894 -0.101161  2.010425e+00
3  0.631818 -0.969503  3.991945e-01

Result of applymap with a regular function
              A         B             C
0  9.115775e-07  4.870592  8.309735e-13
1  4.302793e-05  0.002443  1.851403e-09
2  2.010425e+00  0.010234  4.041807e+00
3  3.991945e-01  0.939936  1.593563e-01

Result of applying with a regular function
              A         B             C
0  9.115775e-07  4.870592  8.309735e-13
1  4.302793e-05  0.002443  1.851403e-09
2  2.010425e+00  0.010234  4.041807e+00
3  3.991945e-01  0.939936  1.593563e-01
```