# How to apply same transformation logic to multiple columns in a single go in python 3.4.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` with multiple columns and I want to apply the same logic to multiple columns at once. I know how to do it for one column at a time but anyone has an idea how to apply the same logic for multiple columns in a single go?

dataframe df

```
col0  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  new_col
row0  24.0    83  42.0     7    96     0   NaN      192
row1  40.0     4   NaN    12    84     0   NaN      168
row2  83.0    22  80.0    26    15     0   NaN       30
row3  92.0    73  58.0     0    33     0   NaN       66
row4   NaN    63  35.0    70    95     0   NaN      190
```

I have to apply some transformation to `col4`, `col5`, `col6`. I am able to do it one by one but how to do it for all the columns at once in a single go?

```
df['col4'] = df['col4'].apply(lambda n: n*2)
df['col5'] = df['col5'].apply(lambda n: n*2)
df['col6'] = df['col6'].apply(lambda n: n*2)
```

Comment: Why do you need the same column (`df['col4'].apply(lambda n: n*2)`) so many times?

Comment: sorry I updated that. that was mistake

Answer (score 3):

It depends of logic. If possible working with all columns like filtered `DataFrame` use:

```
cols = ['col4','col5','col6']

df[cols] = df[cols] * 2

#short version
df[cols] *= 2
```

If need complicated function and need working with each `cell` elementwise use [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
cols = ['col4','col5','col6']
df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(func)
```

Comment: thanks I will try your ans. it will work as updated ques. sorry that was type so updated the ques

Comment: What is the difference between apply and applymap?

Comment: @geckos - Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798153/difference-between-map-applymap-and-apply-methods-in-pandas)