# Is there a faster/better way to apply a function in order to create a new column, across different axes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames that look like this:

df1 (pretty small):

| index | sales |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 20 |

and df2 (very large >5Mil):

| idx1 | idx2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |

and I want the final to look like this:

| idx1 | idx2 | totalSales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 30 |

I currently have this working but it is very slow:

```
df2['totalSales'] = df2.apply(lambda x: df1.loc[x]['sales'].sum(), axis=1)
```

Are there any faster/better ways to go about this?  This works for me just fine, but it takes a very long time to run.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be faster than `apply`:

```
df2['totalSales'] = df2.idx1.map(df1.sales) + df2.idx2.map(df1.sales)

df2 
#   idx1  idx2  totalSales
#0     1     2          30
```

Comment: Hi, what is the difference between `apply` and `map` for a series?

Comment: @RishabhKumar Here is a good explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56300992/4983450. TLDR: `map` is an optimized version that can accept dict / series while `apply` is more flexible but also slower.