# How to put a value to each row of the column name that matches the condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been attempting turn 0 to 1 with pandas if the column name matches the year in each list.
the last `if` statement gives an error.

```
df

+-----------+------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|   start   |    end     | 2012 | 2013 | 2014 | 2015 | 2016 | 2017 | 2018 | 2019 | 2020 | 2021 |
+-----------+------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 2017/1/29 | 2019/9/10  |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| 2012/1/30 | 2015/9/11  |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| 2019/1/31 | 2021/05/08 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| 2016/2/1  | 2017/9/13  |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| 2017/2/2  | 2019/9/14  |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| 2017/2/3  | 2021/05/08 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| 2020/2/4  | 2020/9/16  |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
+-----------+------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+


for index, row in df.iterrows():
 s_year = int(row['start'][:4])
 e_year = int(row['end'][:4])

 l_years = []
 l_years.append(s_year)

 while s_year < e_year:
  s_year += 1
  l_years.append(s_year)

 for i in l_years:
   for column_name in df.columns.values:
    if i == column_name:
     df[index][column_name] = 1
```

Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2897             try:
-> 2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2899             except KeyError as err:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2899             except KeyError as err:
-> 2900                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2901 
   2902         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try broadcasting year columns across rows to create a mask, then replace with 1 where mask is True:

```py
# Ensure Types are Correct
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'])

# Grab Year Columns
year_columns = df.columns[2:]
# Get Year Columns as numpy array as numbers
c = year_columns.to_numpy().astype(int)
# Broadcast start year vs column column (as int) and end year vs year column (as int)
m = ((df['start'].dt.year.to_numpy()[:, None] <= c) &
     (c <= df['end'].dt.year.to_numpy()[:, None]))
# Update year_columns where mask is True
df[year_columns] = df[year_columns].mask(m, 1)
print(df.to_string())
```

`df`:

```
       start        end  2012  2013  2014  2015  2016  2017  2018  2019  2020  2021
0 2017-01-29 2019-09-10     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0
1 2012-01-30 2015-09-11     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
2 2019-01-31 2021-05-08     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1
3 2016-02-01 2017-09-13     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
4 2017-02-02 2019-09-14     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0
5 2017-02-03 2021-05-08     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1
6 2020-02-04 2020-09-16     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
```

---

In terms of correcting your implementation, try iterating over only year columns (excluding 'start' and 'end') as ints instead:

```py
# Ensure Types are Correct
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'])

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # Get years from timestamps
    s_year = row['start'].year
    e_year = row['end'].year

    l_years = []
    l_years.append(s_year)

    while s_year < e_year:
        s_year += 1
        l_years.append(s_year)

    for c_year in l_years:
        # Iterate Over Date Columns Only (Exclude Start and End)
        for col_idx, column_name in enumerate(df.columns[2:].values.astype(int)):
            if c_year == column_name:
                # Replace at index, col_idx + 2 because 'start' and 'end'
                # were excluded so col_idx is off by 2
                df.iloc[index, col_idx + 2] = 1
```

---

Or much more simply:

```py
# Ensure Types are Correct
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'])

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # Get years from timestamps
    s_year = row['start'].year
    e_year = row['end'].year
    # Create Range of years as strings
    l_years = list(map(str, np.arange(s_year, e_year + 1)))
    # Update based on index and year column names
    df.loc[index, l_years] = 1
```

Comment: I had no idea of the use of `to_numpy()` in this case. I will from now on keep it mind that to write code to ensure types are correct in order not to get any possible type error.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try:

```
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'])

def change(x):
    k = range(x['start'].year,x['end'].year+1)
    for col in x.index[2:]:
        if int(col) in k:
            x[col] = 1
    return x
    
df = df.apply(change,1)
```

Comment: To make it a function is easier to notice mistakes later. `apply()` is new to me. I end up hitting the difference between map and apply. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798153/difference-between-map-applymap-and-apply-methods-in-pandas/56300992#56300992)