# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'type' and 'type' . For value_counts method

Tags: python, pandas

I am exploring Pandas method : applymap() on dataframe , and apply() on series

I can't figure out why i get the error when i use the value_counts() on dataframe but not on series.

```
col_1 = list(range(2)) + ["a", "b"] + list(range(2))
df = pd.DataFrame({"col_1": col_1})
df.applymap(type)
```

```
    col_1
0   <class 'int'>
1   <class 'int'>
2   <class 'str'>
3   <class 'str'>
4   <class 'int'>
5   <class 'int'>
```

now if i try df.applymap(type).value_counts() , i will get the error

however, if i try value_counts() on series col_1 instead of df dataframe , i won't get error and receive desired result

```
s= df1["col_1"]
s.value_counts()

output:
<class 'int'>    4
<class 'str'>    2
Name: col_1, dtype: int64
```

it seems to me that the value_counts() method on dataframe has failed to count the string <class 'int'> and <class 'str'> but value_counts() on series can do it

can someone tell me why it is like that ?

Comment: after further investigation, the python type() function return a TYPE of an object which will display on Jupyternotebook as <class 'int'> and <class 'str'> . It is just a display. When we  apply value_counts() on a dataframe object, pandas will try to count unique ROW values and Pandas fails to compare between rows which contains int type and str type. However when we use value_counts() on series , pandas will try to count unique VALUES on a column, and it has succeeded to compare int type and str type. This seems very counterintuitive to me because the comparison has no support on row level

Comment: I think you're right about the row/column thing (see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798153/difference-between-map-applymap-and-apply-methods-in-pandas)). But the interesting part to me is the behavior of `value_counts()`. I'm still having trouble why the element-wise comparison works and the row-wise doesn't. I mean, the working row-wise comp means that it works ***in principle*** for the type objects, no?