# How do I change the values 1 and 2 to female and male in a data frame?

Tags: python

I already have my df. The column I am trying to change is gender. Instead of having 1 and 2 there, I want it to say female or male with 1 being female and 2 being male.

| Gender |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 1 |

Comment: ``df['Gender'] = df.map({1:"female", 2:"male"})`` ?

Comment: Here is a great post that explains [`map`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56300992/4985099) in detail

Comment: @sushanth: Isn't that supposed to be `df['Gender'].map(....)` ? `.map()` is only defined on a series, not a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
df.columns = ['a', 'b']
```

or

```
df_new = df.rename(columns={'1': 'Female', '2': 'Male'})
```

if the column name is not a string

then

```
df_new = df.rename(columns={1: 'Female', ': 'Male'})
```