# can anyone explain to me why this apply() method isn't working?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This doesn't work:

```
def rator(row):
    if row['country'] == 'Canada':
        row['stars'] = 3
    elif row['points'] >= 95:
        row['stars'] = 3
    elif row['points'] >= 85:
        row['stars'] = 2
    else:
        row['stars'] = 1
    return row

with_stars = reviews.apply(rator, axis='columns')
```

But this works:

```
def rator(row):
    if row['country'] == 'Canada':
        return 3
    elif row['points'] >= 95:
        return 3
    elif row['points'] >= 85:
        return 2
    else:
        return 1

with_stars = reviews.apply(rator, axis='columns')
```

I'm practicing on Kaggle, and reading through their tutorial as well as the documentation.  I am a bit confused by the concept.

I understand that the `apply()` method acts on an entire row of a DataFrame, while `map()` acts on each element in a column.  And that it's supposed to return a DataFrame, while `map()` returns a Series.

Just not sure how the mechanics work here, since it's not letting me return rows inside the function...

some of the data:

```
    country description designation points  price   province    region_1    region_2    taster_name taster_twitter_handle   title   variety winery
0   Italy   Aromas include tropical fruit, broom, brimston...   Vulkà Bianco    -1.447138   NaN Sicily & Sardinia   Etna    NaN Kerin O’Keefe   @kerinokeefe    Nicosia 2013 Vulkà Bianco (Etna)    White Blend Nicosia
1   Portugal    This is ripe and fruity, a wine that is smooth...   Avidagos    -1.447138   15.0    Douro   NaN NaN Roger Voss  @vossroger  Quinta dos Avidagos 2011 Avidagos Red (Douro)   Portuguese Red  Quinta dos Avidagos

Index(['country', 'description', 'designation', 'points', 'price', 'province',
       'region_1', 'region_2', 'taster_name', 'taster_twitter_handle', 'title',
       'variety', 'winery'],
      dtype='object')
```

https://www.kaggle.com/residentmario/summary-functions-and-maps

Comment: You mention `map` but you don't show a map implementation. Also can you provide a sample of the `reviews` DataFrame to make your code reproducible?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @user17242583 not really sure it never loads...its the last question in the https://www.kaggle.com/learn/pandas  3rd lesson

Comment: @HenryEcker hey thanks for taking the time, i can add something to the question but its probably easier to copy it from kaggle - but ill try to add a couple of rows!

Comment: that link at the bottom links to the tutorial which has the table at the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `apply`, the function is applied iteratively to each row (or column, depending on the `axis` parameter). The return value of `apply` is not a `DataFrame` but a `Series` built using the return values of your function. That means that your second piece of code returns the stars rating of each row, which is used to build a new `Series`. So a better name for storing the return value is `star_ratings` instead of `with_stars`.

If you want to append this `Series` to your original dataframe you can use:

```
star_ratings = reviews.apply(rator, axis='columns')
reviews['stars'] = star_ratings
```

or, more succinctly:

```
reviews['stars'] = reviews.apply(rator, axis='columns')
```

As for why your first piece of code does not work, it is because you are trying to add a new column: your are not supposed to mutate the passed object. The [official docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) state:

> Functions that mutate the passed object
> can produce unexpected behavior or
> errors and are not supported

To better understand the differences between `map` and `apply` please see the different responses to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798153/difference-between-map-applymap-and-apply-methods-in-pandas), as they present many different and correct viewpoints.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `apply` with a function that modifies the input. You could change your code to this:

```
def rator(row):
    new_row = row.copy()
    if row['country'] == 'Canada':
        new_row['stars'] = 3
    elif row['points'] >= 95:
        new_row['stars'] = 3
    elif row['points'] >= 85:
        new_row['stars'] = 2
    else:
        new_row['stars'] = 1
    return new_row

with_stars = reviews.apply(rator, axis='columns')
```

However, it's simpler to just return the column you care about rather than returning an entire dataframe just to change one column. If you write `rator` to return just one column, but you want to have an entire dataframe, you can do `with_stars = reviews.copy()` and then `with_stars['stars'] = reviews.apply(rator, axis='columns')`. Also, if an `if` branch ends with a return, you can do just `if` after it rather than `elif`. You can also simplify your code with [`cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html).