# Pandas function only works on individual columns but not entire dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have a dataframe like the following (example data given):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'smiles': ['CCCCC', 'CCCC1', 'CCCN1'],
                        'ID' : ['A-111', 'A112', 'A-113'],
              'Parameter_1':[30.0, 31.4, 15.9],
              'Parameter_2':[NaN, '0.644', '4.38E-02'],
              'Date': [dt.date(2021, 1, 1), dt.date(2021, 1, 2), dt.date(2021, 1, 3)]})
```

I have the following function:

```
def num_parse(element):
    try:
        float(element)
        return float(element)
    except ValueError:
        return(element)
    except TypeError:
        return(element)
```

When I apply my function to individual columns it works fine - converting any string that can be floated into a float and leaving all other strings as is and also leaving the datetime column as is.

```
df['Parameter_1'] = df['Parameter_1'].apply(num_parse)
```

When I apply this to my entire dataframe I keep getting the following error:

```
df = df.apply(num_parse)
```

> TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

I am unsure why, please help.

Comment: How do you apply it? `df.applymap(num_parse)` should work

Comment: I misread initially but added how I applied - I was just using df.apply(num_parse) not the method you suggested which does appear to work many thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, `applymap` applies per "cell", while `apply` works per "column", and your function is not vectorized (i.e. cannot accept a Series)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [applymap()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)

```
df.applymap(num_parse)
```

You could also:

```
df.apply(num_parse, axis=1)
```

Comment: This appears to work thank you! How does .applymap() and .apply(), differ? What makes them act on the dataframe differently?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798153/difference-between-map-applymap-and-apply-methods-in-pandas