# How to format labels in scientific notation for bar_label

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I am plotting data in a seaborn barplot. I want to label something from my pandas dataframe into the bar. I have gotten the labeling part figured out (see code to replicate below), but I still want to convert it to scientific notation.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'name': ['experiment1','experiment2'], 'reads': [15000,12000], 'positiveEvents': [40,60]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['proportianPositive'] = df['positiveEvents']/df['reads']

p = sns.barplot(data=df,x='name',y='positiveEvents', palette = 'colorblind', alpha =0.8)
p.bar_label(p.containers[0],labels=df.proportianPositive, padding = -50, rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image: output script above]

How do I convert df.proportianPositive to scientific notation so that it will show up on my barplot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- As already stated, `labels=` supersedes `fmt=`, so they may not be used together.
- `p.containers[0]` → `<BarContainer object of 2 artists>`, which are the properties describing the bars.

  - If using the default height (vertical bars), or width (horizontal bars), then use the `fmt='%.3E'`
  - If using custom labels, the formatting must be applied to the object passed to `labels=`

    - In the case of a `pandas.Series`: `labels = df['proportianPositive'].map(lambda v: f'{v:.3E}')`. See [Difference between map, applymap and apply](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19798153/7758804).
    - For a list-comprehension: `labels = [f'{v:.3E}' for v in df.proportianPositive]`
    - Both options use modern [f-string formatting](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/)
- See [How to add value labels on a bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804) for additional details, and examples, using [`matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html).

#### `fmt=`

```py
ax = sns.barplot(data=df, x='name', y='positiveEvents', palette='colorblind', alpha=0.8)
xa.bar_label(ax.containers[0], fmt='%.3E')
```

[image]

#### `labels=`

```py
ax = sns.barplot(data=df, x='name', y='positiveEvents', palette='colorblind', alpha=0.8)

labels = df['proportianPositive'].map(lambda v: f'{v:.3E}')  # pandas.Series
# labels = [f'{v:.3E}' for v in df.proportianPositive]  # list comprehension
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], labels=labels)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That's probably because the `labels` argument overrides the `fmt` argument. Try formatting the labels:

```
p.bar_label(p.containers[0], padding = -50, rotation=90,
            labels=df.proportianPositive.apply('{:.2e}'.format), 
            )
```

Output:

[image]