# Pandas apply() behaviour in series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am confused as to what happens internally when we use `.apply()` on a Series. As far as I know apply uses vectorization when used on a dataframe while the non vectorized alternative for dataframe is `.applymap()` which performs operations element wise. But when we use `.apply()` on series it also happens element wise so is it not a vecrorized approach/solution?.

If that was the case can't we just use `.map()` on series instead of apply as both does basically the same thing apart from `.apply` being more flexible in terms of using user defined functions with parameters. Is there any performance benefits of using `.apply` on series since it happens element wise anyways, a for loop will do the same thing. Am I missing something here?

As in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798153/difference-between-map-applymap-and-apply-methods-in-pandas?noredirect=1&lq=1) the explanation is about the differences between `apply`, `applymap` and `map`. I am aware of the differences. But the thing which is confusing me is the working of `apply` on a series.
Is it a vectorised operation or it depends on the function and decides whether to use vectorization or not based on the function needs.

Comment: *"As far as I know apply uses vectorization when used on a dataframe"*. Yes and no, it's a simple loop along your axis. It's like a for-loop followed by `your_function(series)`. It depends on `your_function`.

Comment: @Corralien so basically it depends on the function which is being passed like if it is a simple operation it might go with vectorization otherwise it can go about other way?

Comment: If you have a loop in your function, you can't say `apply` is vectorized. `apply` for a series is the same as `map` except, you can't pass a dictionary to `apply` only a callable and you can't pass additional parameters to `map` to pass to your function.

Comment: 'vectorization' can mean various things.  In `numpy` usually we mean using compiled methods to operate on the whole array(s).  It still operates elementwise, but the loop is in faster compiled code.  See the `apply` note regarding `raw=True`.